# Undeserved down-votes

Tags: feature-request

I recently began programming and I realize Stack Overflow is an invaluable resource. I have read the rules and try my best to solve a problem on my own before asking a question. However I realize this site is extremely hostile to newcomers.

I say this because the first two questions that I asked were down-voted, and I feel like I have followed the guide-lines for asking questions. I'm now in danger of being barred from asking a question. Reviewing the questions I asked, I can find no serious issues with them. It seems to me that some users will down-vote a question out of spite when they don't know the solution to the question.

The reason I'm posting here is that I feel some methods should be implemented to give some protection to rule-abiding newcomers. What should be done to protect them?

Comment: 3 questions. 1 upvoted. 1 solvable with a short google search. And 1 without a problem description: "It doesn´t work" or "there is a problem" etc. won´t help us, we can´t read your mind. Describe what the problem is and what is the correct behaviour in your opinion.

Comment: How much more specific can I get with the question on the SQL query? And I did provide the details necessary for a solution. The jQuery question was a mistake that I just couldn't find the solution to and ended up having to ask. EDIT: In fact no, a quick search on google won't answer my jQuery question. If you can reproduce how you found a solution with one search, please tell me what you searched and what link the solution was on.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what downvotes are used for -- they certainly aren't "I don't understand this, so downvote". That's incredibly petty, and as mean as anonymous votes can be, I highly doubt that that would be the case, especially since it's highly improbable that someone could know the answer to every question he/she visits. They usually indicate exactly what the tooltip says -- unclear questions, questions that aren't useful, or questions that don't show any research effort.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you'll get random downvotes despite good questions. You can't do anything about that, and in any case, if your question is good it'll probably be voted up anyways. One thing to keep in mind is that if someone has to ask for clarification in the comments, then you might not have included enough detail. Ideally, you be able to print out your question, mail it to someone else, and receive an answer with the first reply, with no requests for further clarification. Yes, sometimes you might miss something here or there, but those shouldn't be major missing points.

Comment: I understand what down-votes are used for. What I'm saying is some people are abusing this feature.

Comment: And how do you know that?

Comment: Your JQuery question is very bad. you did not do basic debugging (or lack the capability to do so, which is no excuse) and didn't check the documentation. The very first thing you should have done would be breaking the code down into smaller pieces, in this case checking each function individually. It deserves every downvote it got.

Comment: Look at my down-voted questions. Find me a quick solution to the problem using google search. If you can show me an easy way to find a solution to my problems I rest my case.

Comment: For your SQL question, it would be useful if you add the `INSERT` statements. And I'll downvote all answers there, they're all playing the guessing game and the suggested solutions are workarounds for bad data (if whitespace was the problem to begin with) instead of fixing it.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. How do you know that people are abusing downvotes, and more importantly, why do you think it's such a large problem that changes are needed?

Comment: @user3786546 it's not about an "easy way", learning to program is HARD. It's about showing that you invested effort yourself to try and solve this problem, no matter how hard it might be - and if you didn't do so, you should be downvoted. And if you lack the capability to do so, SO is simply not the right place for you. This site is NOT intended to help individual askers or teach you programming basics, it is intended to be a repository of useful knowledge in a Q/A format - think programming wikipedia. Thus, content that's not useful to a broader audience is and should be downvoted.

Comment: Instead of looking for ways to attack me, can you guys look at this in a neutral perspective?

Comment: google "jquery document ready" => go look at [api](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) => realize you're sending two functions instead of one as the api clearly states => solved.

Comment: @ivami when you began programming do you really think you would have been able to solve the problem just like that?

Comment: @user3786546 To be honest, I wouldn't be able to find you a quick solution, because I don't know enough Javascript/MySQL to know if I come across a correct solution. And I sure hope I wasn't one of those people attacking you...

Comment: @user3786546 if you count stating facts about your questions as "attacking you" then yes we are attacking you... with facts. The downvote button reads "This question **does not show any research effort**, is unclear or **not useful**" (emphasis mine) - your jquery question lacked research, the SQL one is a mix of unclear and not useful - unclear as we can't look inside your db to find out what exactly is wrong with the data, and not particularily useful as it is probably an extremely localized error in your data or db.

Comment: @i4mpi What facts were stated? I believe they were just opinions on what I should have done (as an experienced programmer with knowledge a new programmer doesn't have).

Comment: @user3786546: Well, some things are not 100% proofable or really just opinionated. And...? It doesn´t matter. Even without a definite proof that your question is bad, we are allowed to downvote. And downvotes are a peronal thing after all. Each user here can vote on his own accord. Some *do* vote because they don´t like someone or other stupid reasons. But if you receive >10 downvotes, how about thinking that not everybody hates you, but your question *is* in fact bad? Similar for less.

Comment: Fact 1: Not doing research and debugging (or not showing your respective efforts) is a perfectly valid reason for anyone to downvote your question. Fact 2: SO is NOT intended to teach programming or debugging basics, your questions are expected to be useful to a bigger audience - if they are not, this is again a valid reason to downvote. Fact 3: "Not Working" is NOT an acceptable problem description and again a downvote reason. I could probably go on if I'd think it's worth my time - read the comments again, read [all of this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 10):

You deserved every downvote (and upvote) you get.

Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486859/query-for-email-not-working) misses crucial information: what is the current data in the database. Why do you assume your query should return some result? And I am pretty sure it doesn't return `null`, but an empty data set. We have to assume a lot of things to give you an answer -> Bad question. As a result, you receive bad answers.

Your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529583/second-ajax-call-to-one-div-element-not-working) misses all relevant information too. Where is the code for the two divs? How does your code fit in it's context. We have to assume a lot of things to give you an answer -> Bad question. You did receive a decent answer though, so you should be happy.

Your [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668404/uploading-data-from-database-through-php) is actually a complete question with enough information to give a decent answer. And you received a decent answer. And my upvote.

Comment: The crucial information was the collation, which I provided in the first question. The second question had nothing to do with the divs, but the syntax (note that it says the first call works).

Comment: That is not entirely true. You assume it is the collation, but how can we be sure if you don't provide any data? And what is the difference in syntax in your second question? Be specific.

Comment: I didn't assume anything, making a change to the collation was the solution, it worked. The second question, I used a comma instead of semi-colon (which I accept was a dumb mistake but couldn't find the solution as I got no error messages).

Comment: You said you think the collation is the issue, but nothing to support that.

Comment: Please take a second to evaluate your prejudices to new users angry about down-votes and please remove any prejudices you have against them. Now ask yourself this, are there users that abuse down-votes? Possibly. Are there those that down-vote when their answer isn't accepted? Possibly. Should there be a solution to that? I think yes, users that abuse down-votes should be barred from down-voting at the least.

Comment: Again you assume I am prejudged, which I don't like very much. In fact, I believe you might be prejudged since everyone else is evil. We all have been low-rep users some day, and we have all asked stupid questions. But we learn from it and move on. And yes, some people abuse voting, that's why there are things in place to prevent serial upvoting and downvoting, but those users are not likely to measure up against the majority of people voting for real.

Comment: Again, opinion. These users keep asking me how do I know when it's being abuse. Well heres my question to you, how do YOU know how often it's abused. Regardless, I will continue do as much as I can before asking a question on SO. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the majority of the community is abusing it, the community will die of negativity. If you have been around for some time (I have been here for 8 months actively now), you know that most users are here to help you, not downvote every question they see. In fact, they gain nothing with it so why would they?

Comment: @user3786546 As you are the one making the claim, the onus is on *you* to back your claim. Don't shift the burden of proof onto someone asking you to back your claim. Also, I'd really appreciate it if you responded directly to me instead of talking around me. It really makes productive conversation difficult.

Comment: @user3786546 And if you want an answer anyways, here it is: I don't know how often it's abused, because I know that that information is impossible to obtain. I'm sure you realize that finding the intent behind a vote is quite impossible to determine without mind-reading equipment, and if you had that I highly doubt that you would be asking questions on SO in the first place -- just beam into the mind of Jon Skeet and you'd have your answer. Figuring out whether a vote is "abusive" or not is an exercise in futility.

Comment: user3580294 Theres a lot of people commenting here I'm sorry I didn't get around to you. I cannot back the claim just like your second comment says, what I am saying however is that there is a possibility that people abuse down-votes and I will say that there most likely is and that SOME new users are being done wrong. @Patrick obviously it's not the majority, thats not what I'm saying. SO is a high quality site and I can see that comparing it to sites like Quora. I think it should be worth looking at rule-abiding newcomers to protect them.

Comment: @user3786546 But why do you think that this problem is big enough that it warrants a major change to the voting model? And do you think that there are that many *good* questions that end up with a negative score? And how frequently do you think that these are just one-off things that could be brushed off? And how does one determine "rule-abiding"? Isn't that what votes are for?

Comment: Maybe it's not. But I feel it's worth mentioning. Down-vote abuse happens, I can't say how much of a problem it is but I feel it is a problem worth looking at considering. SO is an invaluable resource for aspiring programmers and undeserved bans are... well undeserved.

Comment: @user3786546 The thing is that it's probably quite difficult for an undeserved ban to come about. Several bad questions would need to be asked, which indicates a *pattern* of bad/poor questions, which would mean that the ban probably isn't exactly undeserved. In addition, the most common form of vote abuse -- serial voting -- is already automatically reversed. So what's left is so-called "hit-and-run" downvotes, which are random enough that their effect on a single user is likely negligible.

Comment: That comment is, by far, the most productive. You have made an excellent point and I thank your for that and I rest my case.

Comment: @user3786546 Glad to hear I could help. Sorry there was so much beating around the bush before you could get this resolved.

Answer (score -14):

Many of the ones commenting currently are only focused on attacking me. Regardless, it's not an impossibility that people abuse down-votes, so here is my solution:

Show the OP why he was down-voted and by whom. If the OP feels it is undeserved, report it to the moderator. If the moderator sees that it was a deserved down-vote, give him another point to getting barred from asking questions.

Comment: Everyone thinks downvotes are undeserved, this would never work. Also take a look at [Require an explanation/reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-an-explanation-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question)

Comment: Hooooooly cow, do you have any idea how many times removing anonymity from downvotes has been discussed and rejected?

Comment: Rather than making this poorly defined and articulated feature request, you might want to consider asking a brand new question to discuss why your questions were downvoted, and whether the questions need any improvement or not.

Comment: And I think you could be too fixated on what you perceive to be downvote abuse. Consider how many times downvoted answers actually deserve to be downvoted (many more than "wrongly downvoted" questions), as well as how your proposed feature could be abused as well.... As I stated before, downvote abuse is usually quickly corrected by the rest of the community.

Comment: Note: moderators are not there to judge votes.

Comment: You may also be misunderstanding what the moderators are there for. They're not there to judge correctness, or to decide what is "deserved" (such a thing would be impossible given the huge variety of subjects on SO) -- they're there to ensure the site runs smoothly. Having them moderate individual votes would wreak havoc with their ability to deal with more important tasks.

Comment: It may be possible that what I'm proposing for is for that change that moderators do.

Comment: I think you should 1) read around the meta sites for other suggestions like this, and 2) take a good long look at this suggestion and realize just how flawed it is. Think about how quickly the backlog would build up; the mods already have a decently sized backlog to deal with, and that's just with the existing stuff. Think about how this can be abused, or how quickly this can devolve into dragged-out arguments between the OP and mods about why a vote is deserved or not. And so on and so forth.

Comment: I don't see anyone attacking you. I see a lot of people correcting you, and I see you getting overly defensive about it.

Comment: Please take a second to evaluate your prejudices to new users angry about down-votes and please remove any prejudices you have against them. Now ask yourself this, are there users that abuse down-votes? Possibly. Are there those that down-vote when their answer isn't accepted? Possibly. Should there be a solution to that? I think yes, users that abuse down-votes should be barred from down-voting at the least.

Comment: @user3786546 Yes, there probably are some number of users who don't vote "properly". And how do you know when "abuse" is taking place? And why do you think this problem is so big/pervasive that it needs change? Just the mere possibility isn't reason for significant changes in the voting model -- it needs to actually be causing problems for something to change.