# Getting downvoted yet no comment as to why

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, downvote-reason

The last question I asked got 2 downvotes, yet no comments as to why, I have asked several people I know that use SO, and the only reason I got back was "You didn't use JSBin". I am wanting to improve my "question asking", however with no comments mentioning why I get downvoted I cannot see any way to improve.

The link is [InstantClick not binding to dynamic href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937876/instantclick-not-binding-to-dynamic-href)

Is there any reason as to why SO allows downvoting without leaving a comment? And why would my question, which I feel is appropriately in depth enough get downvoted?

Comment: **[Require an explanation/reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/456814)**.

Comment: See also [meta-tag:downvote-reason].

Comment: And the [grandaddy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) of the duplicates.

Comment: Darn it, I [lost my keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again.

Comment: @TimPost - you really should get a key chain.

Comment: ...It seems like this is the topic of every 7th question.  Please search for duplicates before asking.

Comment: I have upvoted your question there - it **is** a good question - but I have downvoted this one, exactly due to what the downvote button says. The collection of questions about this same topic - most of them more elaborate than this - is already too damn high. Do some search first, for you are not going to get for answers anything that hasn't already been said about downvote justification.

Comment: No good reason I would think. I would make it a requirement that any downvote must be accompanied by a comment of a certain amount of characters minimum.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In all honesty, the concept of negative reputation is something that is .. hard to design around properly, if you're going to employ it. While the two are arguably the same signal - receiving *zero* votes and little attention is quite a bit less jarring than receiving a down vote. But it's not *you* that they're voting on, they're voting on the perceived usefulness of your question *as added to the collection that is the site*. That's .. subjective.

Folks could be voting because they don't like jQuery, and think questions about the library diminish the perceived quality of the site for JS programmers (or, perhaps dilute the usefulness). It's hard to say, I don't think there's anything wrong with your question, I'm also a bit amazed that it received down-votes.

Anyway, my point - if you're going to thrive here, in a system that employs the concept of negative reputation (albeit with guard rails) - you have to be able shake it off if you're certain there's nothing wrong with the question. We don't want to *require* a reason (though we do firmly suggest that users give one) because that opens up a can of yuck.

- "You made me leave a comment, and he went and down-voted all my recent posts to get revenge!"
- "I'm not down-voting stuff because in the time I have for the site, I don't have time to engage with the authors that deeply, can't I just vote on what I think is useful or not?"
- "We're volunteers, but 8,234 comment flags per day for us moderators to handle is just too much."

.. it goes on. When you see a down vote, it could be signal - it could be noise. It's up to you to take a look at your post and decide. *Most* users are helpful and will leave at least a clue as to why they down-voted, but some don't.

If there's nothing wrong with your post, chalk it up to phases of the moon and just move on - the actual point hit is negligible, yet worrying about it is so very costly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the reply, and I now understand the possible issues with introducing a feature such as negative rep.

Comment: Great answer .. but the first point you made is highly wrong! Comments as reason of downvote could be totally anonymous.

Comment: I don't see how one can "shake it off" if it contributes to a question ban.