# Getting a downvote with no comment, on an answer where I help write the library in question, leaving my answer below 0 - acceptable solutions

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I'm aware we've got quite a lot of questions here on downvotes without comments, such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267498/getting-downvoted-yet-no-comment-as-to-why) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). I've had a read through those already.

TL;DR, I (and some others) have answers we've posted on our own libraries at -1 when "less-good" ones are at 0, potentially confusing new users, and want to know what's allowed to get it "fixed" (to at least even on 0)

*Update:* Well I did, until you all found them and upvoted my answers of the type mentioned... General question still remains, especially so I can point other open source developers I meet with the same issue to a solution which doesn't ideally require them to post about it here on meta!

Recently, I've had a few times where people have asked questions about using an Open Source library that I help maintain, adding the tag for the project themselves. (I actually help with a few projects, but there's on in particular). The library is fairly well used, but doesn't seem to get that move love on StackOverflow, and questions + answers tend to stay at fairly low scores, especially compared to some tags. Not the end of the world, I got the Unsung Hero from it.

My problem is that a few times now, people have downvoted my answers without comments, where I know my answer to be correct, since I help write the library in question, and often added unit tests based on the OP's question to verify fixes! You then end up with a 0-voted less-good answer above mine at -1, which isn't as good. One case recently another person who'd commented on the question expressed bafflement that my answer was downvoted to -1, and voted me back up. Other cases, my answer remains at -1, for no apparent reason.

Speaking with another friend today who also helps work on an open source library with fair usage but low votes, they've also been affected by the same thing. They also find it baffling, and it has put them off answering on StackOverflow on their own library, which is clearly not a good result for anyone.

The drop of -2 rep points is something I can cope with, given how many I have, and the "you're wrong" my ego can cope with, as I know I'm right as I work on the library! Since the downvote had no comment, I don't know what was wrong. Maybe they were grumpy that I told them they had to upgrade to a newer version for a fix, maybe they're grumpy that the fix wasn't added until the reported it, maybe something else entirely, I'll never know, so I can't fix/help. What worries me is newbies coming along, seeing my correct answer as -1 and a less good one at 0, and following the less-good advice.

I know a few people offline who use StackOverflow a bit, and I know quite a few people on other StackExchange sites. I could, since there are only a few, reach out to some people who don't really know the library and ask them to upvote my answer. However, I feel a bit bad about doing that, without checking here first. I could ask other people from the project to join StackOverflow then upvote their first answer then have them upvote mine, but again that feels a little off. The line between sock-puppet and meat-puppet then also seems a little blurry. I could do either, but that doesn't help my other friend (well, unless they use me as their meat-puppet...)

In the case where someone get a downvote to -1 with no comment, on a question where they help write the library in question so know for sure that they're right, where there aren't buckets of votes going around, and where "worse" answers then show above (eg at 0), what is the StackOverflow "socially acceptable" way to respond?

Comment: Note that "correct" does not mean "high quality". I'm not saying your answers aren't high quality, but just being a contributor to the project doesn't mean you are going to automatically have upvote-worthy posts.

Comment: Don't _fix_ downvotes with unsolicited upvotes. Did the question really deserve an upvote by means of what you see at the buttons tooltip?

Comment: `I could ask other people from the project to join StackOverflow then upvote their first answer then have them upvote mine, but again that feels a little off. The line between sock-puppet and meat-puppet then also seems a little blurry.` That's not blurry at all.  It's a crystal clear case of voting fraud.

Comment: The solution to "my posts are getting downvotes and not upvotes" is to write better answers that readers will think are of higher quality.  That's pretty much it.  There may be anomalies here and there, but if your posts are regularly getting downvotes and not upvotes, it's a pretty strong sign that they content is simply not valuable to those reading it.

Comment: It's a legitimate concern, but I'm not sure there's a whole lot that can be done for as long as the post doesn't get the *views* it needs for additional votes to happen in the first place. You *could* invoke the meta-effect instead of employing socks or meat puppets, but I'd imagine you'd find that iffy too.

Comment: Check the [tag:ormlite] library, the primary contributor of this library, [Gray](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray) is a good example of a contributer who writes good answers about his library. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Servy I've got over 20k of rep, so most of my posts are found to be of at least OK quality. I can't spot anything obviously different between the ones which get 0/+1, and the ones that get -1 when other people's stay at 0

Comment: @Gagravarr If you're only ever considering posts evaluated by a single person, then you have to accept the fact that different people have different standards, as well as different qualifications for evaluating posts.  In aggregate, this isn't really a problem, when exclusively considering posts with one vote, it's rather apparent.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Looks to be a library with a slightly higher amount of upvotes per question, but otherwise broadly similar. In aggregate my answers are apparently fine, as I've hit >20k rep, it's the cases described in the question where I'm having the issue (+ other people I know in open source who are less into StackOverflow are having it & giving up)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm not too fussed about a lack of upvotes, I've got enough rep already! It's the downvotes with no other upvotes that I'm wondering about. (And are putting off other Open Source developers who I've come across, which is probably not ideal for the growth of the community)

Comment: @Gagravarr Sometimes I find it helpful to explain in my answers why the solutions presented in other answers are not as permanent/maintainable/workable. So for instance, my answer would say something like "It's not enough to just do X, because that will give you trouble down the line when Y happens. Unlike solution X, this solution will continue to work even if you decide to implement Z."

Comment: @BoltClock I deliberately chose not to include any links, as I didn't want to invite sympathy up-votes. I'm not too fussed about my own case either. However, next time I'm talking to someone at an open source event / conference / list / etc, and they moan about this problem on StackOverflow, I'd like to be able to tell them what to do to fix it and stay involved in the community, rather than have them get upset / annoyed and leave StackOverflow, which doesn't help anyone :/

Comment: I don't think <insert rep amount here> rep is an indicator of being able to create quality content when you receive more than double the amount of rep for an upvote than you lose for a downvote. My most upvoted answers are often times some of my worse, simply due to the popularity of very basic questions.

Comment: You don't have _any_ negatively-scored answers. Have you been deleting the ones you're talking about?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I did before writing the post... People seem to have found them and upvoted them all in the last hour!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the other option, but it didn't look like you had enough rep gain in the last little while.

Comment: @Josh I thought the same, but the previously negatively voted answers (-1 score) have 0 votes on them.

Answer (score 23):

As a counterpoint, I am an author of [a fairly popular open source library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpuimage) and I've not experienced any of the downvoting you mention.

The only questions I tend to answer nowadays are ones about that framework. I do so not because I care about votes or reputation, but because I know that often I'm the only one who can answer the question. None of these answers have tremendous numbers of upvotes, but they gather upvotes slowly over time as people come across the same issues. They're great as a publicly searchable FAQ listing, and have cut down on the number of similar questions I get asked in my GitHub issues or via email.

I've seen some library authors receive downvotes on their answers when the answers themselves were not great. A lot of people who aren't familiar with Stack Overflow have a tendency to post answers that are little more than links ("My library would be great for this: [link]", "Refer to issue #xxx on GitHub: [link]", etc.). Those answers sometimes get downvoted because they lack sufficient information within them to answer the question.

In other cases, library authors ask for people to contact them offsite to resolve issues, which isn't looked upon well here. Yet others get a little too aggressive with promotion of their library.

All I can say is that if you focus on writing detailed, descriptive answers and disclose that you're the author of the library in question, I think you'll find the community to be very receptive to those answers. Again, you're most likely not going to get a tremendous number of upvotes for them, due to the more limited audience, but they can greatly help out users of your library.