# Is it possible to lose a privilege if you lose the required reputation for it?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, privileges

I have 125 rep exactly,  which is the number I need to start downvoting, according to [Help Center > Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). If I go and downvote a post right now, will I lose my downvoting privileges?

Comment: Yes, you will lose them. Try to give yourself a buffer.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you say that you want to downvote "someone", instead of downvoting a question or an answer?

Comment: I didn't realize (until now) that there was a difference.  When I said "someone" I mean either.

Comment: @alex0112, the reason Cupcake brings that up is because you should be focusing on the post, not the person posting it. But not a big deal; it sounds like you are not using it the wrong way.

Comment: @alex0112 can you accept gunr's answer instead, it's better, and I'd rather delete mine.

Comment: @Cupcake For what reason?  It seems to me like you answered the question up front at the beginning of the answer, and then proceeded to cite a source from the site explaining it in further detail.  I thought it was a good answer, but perhaps there's something I'm not considering.

Comment: @alex0112 well, if you feel that my answer is the best one, that is your choice and I will respect that. The reason I bring it up, however, is because my answer didn't address the key part of your question (at first), which was that *it's not obvious that you can lose earned privileges*. [It's not explicitly stated in the Help Center](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/is-it-possible-to-lose-a-privilege-if-you-lose-the-required-reputation-for-it#comment72280_267707), as far as we could tell.

Comment: Heh, I have first-hand experience of this *multiple* times - being right at 2k rep, every time a question I'd edited got deleted, I had to go edit another question to get the LQP queue back (until I found another question to answer. I do moderation-type things a lot more than I answer questions. :p)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It depends on *what* you're downvoting:

- Downvotes on *questions* are free, and cost no rep.
- Downvotes on *answers* will cost you 1 rep.

According to the [downvote privilege in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), it says:

> #### What happens when I vote down?
>
> When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so
> it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something
> we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.
>
> - Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post owner.
> - Downvotes on answers remove **1** reputation from you, the voter.
> - Downvotes on questions are **free**. ([Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))
> - You can vote **30** times per UTC day. You get an additional **10** votes on questions only.
>   ([Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))

[As pointed out by gunr2171](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267707/456814), your privileges are based on your *current* reputation level. When you earn a privilege, you don't get to keep it permanently if you end up losing the required reputation for it later.

Comment: Though I agree with the down vote policies, as a person who used to get tons of down votes, it is a pain to try to recover the question. So I end up deleting it, and rewrite. Some times it resulted in up votes, and other times it resulted in more down votes. This could have been avoided if people would be inspired to comment their down votes. Then I would understand what I was over assuming on, when I wrote the question. Just raising awareness, not suggesting any changes. (I did delete the account that started down a path of very negative score.)

Comment: @Brian there is so much going on in your one comment that I *must* comment on...I'll do so eventually, but for now I have to go.

Comment: Fair enough. Short: I will always comment on why I down vote. I hope other people will too.

Comment: Brian, many are woried to tell they downvoted you, because there were cases of revenges before.

Comment: "Downvotes on questions are free"... YES!!!!

Comment: @Brian, I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't deleting the question get rid of the negative downvotes? Or couldn't you delete all those questions because some of them got some answers upvoted?

Comment: @VladimirF, that is why I don't ask for a policy change, just want to inspire to post comments on down votes.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, yes, I could have. But when you cannot get answers, and you don't know why you are getting down voted, and it seems to be on all questions posted, why bother. This is why I comment. So people can understand the reason for the down vote, otherwise they will never correct, and they will continue to get down votes until they learn. That is a short path to frustration.

Comment: @Brian okay, I've been getting nothing but notifications about this all day, so I'll respond with this, and if I have time later, I'll follow up with everything else I wanted to point out about your comment. Please read [Require an explanation/reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/456814) and [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135). I also encourage you to read up on the posts in the [meta-tag:downvote-reason] tag, even the downvoted questions.

Answer (score 32):

You have privileges based on the reputation that you *currently have*, not that you *did have*.

This means that if you have the minimum rep required for a privilege and then lose rep (in any way), you will also lose your new privileges.

In the case where you have 125 rep, the minimum for downvoting, and you downvote an answer (which costs you 1 rep), you will have 124 rep, and thus no downvote ability. Note that downvoting a question is free (no rep lost).

My advice is to get a few more rep points as a buffer.

Comment: So this brings up an interesting question: *where* in the help center does it actually say that you can lose privileges if you lose the rep required to posses them?

Comment: True, I have not seen the exact phrase myself. The only reason I know this is because it happened to me around the 2k mark.

Comment: @Cupcake: You could consider it implied. Since a privilege is tied to having a given rep level, it makes sense that you don't have the privilege whenever you do not have the rep level, independent of previous history. But it would be good to document that specifically if it's not there. Particularly since badges work differently, and you don't lose them once you got them, even if you don't meet the conditions anymore.

Comment: That is not true of badges it seems tho. I was the victim of a serial upvoter (some noob thought he/she could show gratitude by upvoting a bunch of my posts) This triggered one of my answers to hit 10 upvotes and I was given a badge for it. When the upvote reversal took place, the badge stuck around

Comment: True. Badges are not taken away. They are a reward for something you have achieved. When you win a game, you get a cup that you can keep. A couple of years later, you may not play so well anymore and you are no longer allowed into the stadium, but you can still keep the cup.

Comment: @Cupcake No time to find the exact link, but the scenario of loosing the rep below some threshold and loosing privileges associated with it is mentioned in the description of bounties. It is an exact analogy, although it's true that usually users encounter scenario described in this question first, so this should be also mentioned in some "earlier" part of the Help Center.