# Why does the "You earned the privilege" achievement not disappear when I lose reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, achievements-dialog

I had posted an answer and got an upvote for it.So I got the "create tag synonyms" privilege(Since I got 2.5K rep). Then,the OP edited his code telling there was a mistake in it which made my answer incorrect. By that time,two other users had answered the edited question correctly.So I deleted my answer and I lost 10 reputation and my reputation dropped down below 2.5K (2494 rep to be exact).

But still,the reputation tab shows that I've earned the privilege.Why does it not disappear when I lose some reputation?

[image: Screenshot with the reputation tab opened]

Comment: Well, you still have earned it in the past... Your subsequently losing that privilege does not mean we have to rewrite history:) It would be interesting to know if you receive a second message when you earn the privilege again, but I strongly suspect you won't (receive another message, not earn the privilege again).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ,Yeah.That makes sense.And you are right again.I didn't receive the "you earned the privilege" for the second time.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

We don't take away achievements (unless they were awarded following fraudulent behavior).

You achieved the privilege - right? That you lost rep and therefor also lost the privilege doesn't mean you never achieved it.

You will not be notified again of regaining the privilege once your reputation goes back up.

Comment: It would be a great added feature to receive notification when you did regain your privileges.

Comment: Note that http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/is-it-possible-to-lose-a-privilege-if-you-lose-the-required-reputation-for-it?rq=1 states opposite. Does "we don't take away achievements " apply to all privileges or just some (like in linked question 125 rep for downvoting)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - you are conflating _achievements_ with _privileges_. That you _achieved_ ad privileges at one time, but later on lost the privilege, doesn't mean you did not achieve it in the first place.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but it seems like quite a semantic difference given that you don't have anything tangible left. Contrast with badges where you do get to keep the actual publicly visible thing even if the conditions go away.

Comment: @Ganesh - it is an event. Something that happened. If you see the notice, then lose rep, can we make you unsee it?

Comment: @Oded you are absolutely right - I was mixing them up... "achieved privilege, but no longer have it now" makes sense.

Comment: No, but  it's confusing not to then be shown the reverse event.

Comment: Sometimes this is annoying - for example if you've been serially upvoted.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I agree, but I think it's more beneficial to SO to not generate a negative atmosphere by shoving "unachievements" in people's faces. As it is now (need to know basis) seems like a good balance.

Comment: @Andreas Perhaps if the "unachievement" was accompanied by a picture of [Nelson](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110623042517/simpsons/images/4/40/Picture0003.jpg), it wouldn't be so negative?

Comment: @Oded In [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323431/3603374) . The user earned  edit community wikis privilege  before hitting 100 rep mark. 
Is something wrong there?

Comment: @Sandeep - you missed the first comment on that post. The OP got the rep then lost it.

Comment: @Oded but no negative rep is shown in users [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4593127/silentmonk?tab=reputation)?

Comment: @Sandeep - there is a 5 minute grace period for retracting votes. If someone upvotes then retracts it, this will not show up.

Comment: Isn't the real reason that it would be to complicated to implement that kind of code? Just think about it: What if the downvote privilege would be removed, how would you implement "remember all downvotes while not having the privilege" considering a downvote removes reputation, or links suddenly not working anymore, and other stuff I did not even think about.