# Getting award for achieving the down vote privilege without any reputation changes inside account

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This question is not a duplicate of [Why does the “You earned the privilege” achievement not disappear when I lose reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277673/why-does-the-you-earned-the-privilege-achievement-not-disappear-when-i-lose-re) because that question shows clearly that the user got some reputation before he got his privileges

I answered a question today, and suddenly I received the close vote privilege. While recieving privileges is good, it doesn't make sense since there wasn't any reputation change inside my account as seen on the following page on my account.

[image: my account that is showing that there wasn't any reputation changes in the past]

Comment: Most likely there was an upvote on a post of yours followed by an immediate unupvote.  That wouldn't be shown in the rep logs, but would have put you above 125 rep for a short period of time.

Comment: @Servy How can I check this?

Comment: I doubt you can, nor is it particularly worth worrying about at all anyway.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SE: [Badges that I have not yet earned are shown in achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330661/289905).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this, on your profile:

> [image: no net reputation changes]

Why bother with it if there were no rep changes?

Well, that's not true - there *were* rep changes, but the sum total (net) of them was zero.

That means there were some votes happening that got reversed (most likely an upvote, taking you over 125, followed by an un-upvote).

Now, you were briefly over 125, so you got the privilege - and a notification was sent and received.

We don't retract notifications, so you saw that, even though that by the time you got it, you lost the privilege :/

Comment: I never know the rep changes on the account where combined per question or per day, since rep changes are mostly sorted by question on this list. I will remember this for the future

Comment: @ferrybig - you have 3 different display options for rep (graph, by time and by post).

Comment: Maybe the initial notice could be re worded to indicate that the privilege may or not persist based on certain factors.  This may reduce confusion. Probably also better than also sending retraction notices.