# Why did I get the 'Set Bounties' privilege before I should have?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I'm currently on 72 reputation points. However, when I logged in just now it seems I have been awarded the privilege early. It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) that I shouldn't expect that level of privilege until my reputation is >= 75.

What's going on here? Is this a common bug, or have I missed something?

Comment: Perhaps somebody upvoted one of your answers (putting your reputation at 82 and triggering the message), and then changed his/her mind and canceled the upvote.

Comment: Related question of mine: [Getting award for achieving the down vote privilege without any reputation changes inside account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280575/getting-award-for-achieving-the-down-vote-privilege-without-any-reputation-chang)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It shows here, you don't have the privilege:

[image]

Which means that the reason in @[Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333756/i-got-the-set-bounties-privilege-before-i-should-have#comment390735_333756) is most likely the cause of it:

> Perhaps somebody upvoted one of your answers (putting your reputation at 82 and triggering the message), and then changed his/her mind and canceled the upvote.

A transient upvote of one of your posts would've taken it to 77 (for a question) or 82 (for an answer), triggering the notification for the privilege. Or possibly an answer accepted then unaccepted.