# Got a notification that a privilege has been earned even though my reputation is less than the reputation required to earn the privilege

Tags: bug

I got a notification that I have earned privilege to "edit community wikis" which requires 100+ reputation. But I my reputation is 98.

As pointed out in the comments by @sandeep, I don't see any negative reputation in my profile. Also, I was online when I got this privilege and my reputation was 98.

Adding an image as requested.

[image]

Posting the reputation details which show no loss of reputation.It is currently 100 but I got +2 after the question was posted.

[image]

Comment: You hit the trigger rep, then lost a bit.

Comment: @MartinJames but I don't see any negative votes in this user's [Reputation Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4593127/silentmonk?tab=reputation).

Comment: @Sandeep OK, maybe it's 'less positive' rep ;)

Comment: @MartinJames, is there a way to check this so that if that is the issue, this can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinJames Then, how can he hit the trigger? his rep is 98.

Comment: @SilentMonk  Can u share screenshot of earned privilege message.

Comment: @Sandeep I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Most likely a post you edited has been deleted - you lose the +2 rep you gained from the approved edit.

Comment: It's possible someone upvoted/unupvoted or accepted/unaccepted one of your posts. If that happened quickly enough it won't show in the reputation history, but the privilege trigger may actually have been hit.