# Stack Overflow Privileges

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Why do I need to get more than 50 Reputation again to comment on answers after I have used 50 Reputation for bounty?

Why aren't privileges declared as rights I can keep until I get banned/kicked or something like that?

I found some sources where people said that privileges are forever but they aren't or just for me ;)

This is really annoying...

Comment: badges are pretty much "forever", privileges are not badges

Comment: yeah, but I want to comment. And I got over 50 reputation before the bounty. so why do I need to get them again? this is not logical.

Comment: [That's just the way it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/258928). If you loose rep for whatever reason and that loss make you go under any privilege threshold, you loose that privilege. It is the same when you downvote answers. This has to be taken into consideration when downvoting/rewarding bounties.

Comment: Yes but that is not the way it should be done. Its not User friendly. Its the same like the following example: You bought a ticket for a disco and want to go outside for a moment and you get a stamp on your hand to get back into the disco. Then you lost your original ticket outside but you want to get back in. But the bouncer don't want to let you in again because you have lost your ticket. But you have your stamp on the hand which says that you have been inside and paid."

Comment: Well, SO ain't no disco. If you spend [a day in the penalty box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) so your rep gets temporarily reset to 1, but you would still have all your privileges, that ban would have no effect at all.

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267707/3001761

Comment: one good Q or A and you will be back to 50.

Comment: "Privileges as rights until revoked" doesn't work on a site on which it is trivial to create an unlimited number of sock puppet accounts. That's basic online community 101.

Comment: _I found some sources where people said that privileges are forever_ Were those sources on Stack Overflow or another Stack Exchange site? If so, can you point to them so that someone can correct the post?

Comment: _Then you lost your original ticket outside but you want to get back in._ Using a bounty is more like giving someone else your ticket.

Comment: @Jongware Have you read the question? The OP wrote: "... until I get banned".

Comment: @D4V1D That's just the way that makes no sense. How can I earn a privilege by contributing to the site while loosing it at the same time for contributing to the site? Isn't this a contradiction? Why 10 guys down-vote a guy who is asking about an obvious contradiction?

Comment: @hek2mgl this is likely to prevent abuse. If you think of it, if it was the way you dream of, a guy with 99 rep would be able to stuff 50 rep bounty to their buddy / sock puppet and get them enabled to do comments, upvotes and other stuff - and still keep the privileges they acquired. Then this happy pair could vote up each other and "elect" third buddy / sock to be stuffed with bounty and get privileges and so on. Without throttling bound to current rep, system would be much less reliable and harder to moderate

Comment: these downvotes everytime... It's just the fact that this is no community :D and I don't complain about the reputation as everyone might thinks. Im talking about the fact that privileges I earned will be revoked when I lost reputation. Which is as always the example that only the "rich" guys stays on top and keep their privileges #bad_practice

Comment: @Snickbrack I'm with you about the poorness of the Meta community, but don't let us extend the discussion too much about "arm and rich", because this doesn't apply here. Basically I'm wondering why one can earn privileges trough contributing to the site, while he will loose them afterwards - through contributing to the site. You've asked that, and that's a valid question.

Comment: why is this practice `[...] basic online community [...]`? where did you get the definition from?

Comment: @gnat If the privilege of offering a bounty would be that critical it would not being awarded as one of the first privileges - available at 75 points, compared too 1000 (see vote counts). Isn't it? Your sock puppet argumentation makes no sense.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Do you refer to this http://www.amazon.com/Community-101-How-Grow-Online/dp/1600051529?

Comment: @hek2mgl it looks like you've got it the other way 'round. I think it's important to give bounty privilege as early as possible, to let askers bring additional attention to their questions, and dropping privileges with the rep just helps to make it possible by lowering risk of bounty abuse by low rep users

Comment: I basically asking myself why a user who asks a question on a support site - of a company who earns money and who's product he is using, can be treated that unkindful. Unclear IHMO. period. On the other hand I'm asking myself whether the privilege model still makes sense in the way how it is implemented today. I see so much pooooor posts upvoted every! Oh man, this started since a year. I've flagged such a post and moderators accepted the flag but told "what should we do". IMHO we should talk about privileges and don't down-vote such - valid - questions here.

Answer (score 15):

> Why do I need to get more than 50 Reputation again to comment on
>   answers after I have used 50 Reputation for bounty?

Because you no longer have the required reputation. It doesn't matter *how* you lose the rep, whether you give a bounty, get downvotes or lose upvotes (e.g. someone reverses their vote or a post gets deleted); privileges are tied to your **current reputation**.

> Why aren't privileges declared as rights I can keep until I get
>   banned/kicked or something like that?

That's just not how SO works. As above, it's your current reputation that matters, not your peak reputation.

> I found some sources where people said that privileges are forever

I don't know where you found that, but those people are incorrect!

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP asked for the reasoning behind this.

Comment: @hek2mgl if you have a better answer, write it

Comment: An answer which explains the reasoning behind *why* SE has decided to do so can only be given by an SE official. Why did you wrote the answer? What did you had in mind? Helping? Discussion? Making the OP look like an idiot? I can't see the reasoning behind it. Please tell me.