# Why does giving a Bounty reduce your ranking on SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, reputation-leagues

I recently placed my first bounty on Stack Overflow. I understand that by placing a bounty on a question, I am giving away some of my rep in an attempt to get a better answer / draw more attention to the question.

What I do not understand however, is why that should impact on my `ranking`:

[image: top 42% this year]

Before I placed the bounty, I was in the top 30-something% this year, and after placing the bounty, I've been lowered to 42%.

This tells me that ranking system just looks at `Total Rep Gained - Total Rep Lost`. Which doesn't really provide a fair ranking.

**Why?**

The reasons I feel this is unfair, is because the ranking system should be looking at who the `"best"` users are.

By placing a bounty on a question it does not make the user any worse, it just means that the user wants a better / quicker / [insert other reason here..] answer.

Shouldn't the rankings only be looking at `Total Rep Gained - Total Rep Lost from Downvotes`?

Comment: Because when you take out the bounty, the amount of reputation comes off your total immediately.

Comment: Surely SO stores the 'reputation change reasons'? Whats the problem in excluding Bounty's from the ranking? -I don't believe this is a technical issue, I believe it's by design.

Comment: the ranking is "whoever progressed more in terms of rep". So yeah, opening a Bounty makes you regress in rep, so this is working as intended

Comment: @Patrice - Ahh, so it's not a "Best User Ranking"? - I think you could place that as an answer!

Comment: @KidCode Take a look at this similar question to see just how by design the reputation system is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/is-it-possible-to-lose-a-privilege-if-you-lose-the-required-reputation-for-it .

Comment: Wow, 5 downvotes for not understanding that the ranking system was rep gained so far vs "best" users...

Comment: @KidCode voting is different on meta. It doesn't even cost you rep :) don't fret it ^^

Comment: in this case I'd point the finger at the usage of the word "unfair" which people likely disagree with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reputation leagues, which is what that ranking is for, keep track of your total reputation changes for certain periods of time: All-time, Year, Quarter, Month, and Week.

Let's say you had gained 300 rep so far this year. You then placed a 50 rep bounty, making your total rep change thus far in the year 250. This drop in your total change therefore puts you slightly lower in the list.

Keep in mind that these leagues are really more for fun than anything. There's nothing for getting super high in the list, no prizes, not even badges. It's all just for fun, so don't sweat it too much.