# Should users lose rights after awarding bounties?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty, privileges

I appreciate that there is a point system in place so that new users do not have too much power over the community when they start out. If anyone could sign up and edit/delete someone else's answers, that would be a problem.

However, when a user has gained the privilege to view up/down/close votes, or edit posts, or write comments, it seems counter-intuitive to take those rights away because they gave away a bounty. This would, in my mind, create an atmosphere where we discourage participation in the community, because giving away a bounty becomes ***worse*** than a 0-sum game.

Perhaps this isn't as much of a problem for some of the higher-rep users as others, however, I find myself permanently in reputation-purgatory because my questions are sufficiently boring enough to require bounties.

***EDIT:*** This post was marked as a duplicate of [Why does giving a Bounty reduce your ranking on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303327/why-does-giving-a-bounty-reduce-your-ranking-on-so). However, that *question* asks why bounties effect rep. Here I honestly don't care about rep, I care about privileges, and I am putting forward the motion that there should be two separate scores in the database for each user. Their rep, and their rep minus any bounties. The former decides your privileges, and the latter your visible rep. I am not asking why it is currently the way it is :)

Comment: What then would stop me giving away all my rep as bounties if I kept all the privileges?

Comment: You lose all your rep..?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/exclude-bounties-from-affecting-privileges

Comment: So, if you give away rep in bounties, you cannot ever loose any associated privileges, unless you get a manual suspension? That doesn't seem like such a stellar idea...

Comment: @J.J so what if I lose all my rep and keep my privileges, what else is my rep good for?

Comment: @CodeGray ahh, i tried really hard to find if this had been posted before, because of course im not the first person to lose privileges over a bounty. Damn. I'll close this then and read those.

Comment: To reply to Robert, rep is not just about privileges. If it were, there would be no need to display it anywhere :) Rep is a currency, in my opinion, for work. I work hard at answering question, i build up enough rep to ask a question with a bounty.

Comment: @RobertLongson you will be well away from your next privilege. I somewhat agree to this idea, but maybe in this way: you give rep for bounty which deducts your privileges...but after a delay, say 2-3-X days. This way you can still use the privilege and if you are committed enough you will re-gain the rep in time for no disruptions ?

Comment: Well, you probably searched here. Those discussions were had a long time ago, back when there was only one Meta site for all the Stack Exchange sites. Not blaming you for being unable to find them. And this isn't actually a duplicate, because those were asked on another site.

Comment: @J.J Yes but I have all the privileges there are and so does Cody. We and many others could just flood the place with bounties.

Comment: If you routinely ask questions that only attract an answer after putting a bounty on it, and don't earn it back like bounties questions often do, then *maybe* you don't understand the site as well as you need to.  And maybe there should be a consequence for boring users.  And maybe getting 11% less reputable isn't the end of the world either.   Enough maybies, maybe :)

Comment: see also [Is it possible to lose a privilege if you lose the required reputation for it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267704/is-it-possible-to-lose-a-privilege-if-you-lose-the-required-reputation-for-it)

Comment: I like the current system for simplicity's sake; is easy and simple to understand. More special logic means more edge-cases and possibly more "creative" ways to abuse it, as well as (probably) more confused users.

Comment: Me too - im a big fan of simplicity. However, it probably wouldn't be so complicated to have an extra stat on each user for "bounty awarded". That would be an interesting stat in its own right, and would solve this issue if it was added to the rep to determine privileges.

Comment: [extra stat like this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered) "271 Offered bounties for 26,850 reputation "

Comment: Awesome! So the data is all already there. The only thing that would need to change is when privilege gets recalculated, it uses rep+total_bounty rather than just rep.

Comment: Rep is directly correlated to privileges, so I'm not seeing why this question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Because the point of the request was specifically to not correlate them to privileges?

Comment: Stop asking boring questions!

Comment: Hehehe :P Unfortunately I live a boring life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not losing privileges based on reputation loss from bounties would open some loopholes to be exploited. If your loss of privileges was based on a calculation that included bounties such as rep + bounties it would cause issues when a user gives away a significant amount of their reputation via bounties.

Under a system like that it would be possible to give away all the reputation they have leaving them with a total of 1 rep. Once they hit that level they will no longer have rep loss from downvotes and be unable to lose privileges through the downvote system and they would have to be manually removed.

I know it is a little extreme to say a person would give all their rep away, but that is likely one of the concerns with not losing privileges from lost rep to bounties.

Comment: Woah - that makes total sense.

OK, I was wrong - I now vote in favour of keeping it the way it is. :)

Comment: @J.J Consider also this abuse scenario: I bounty away my rep to a coworker. My rep goes down, but my "rep counting towards privileges" stays the same. My co-worker's rep goes up, and so does their "rep counting towards privileges". Even stopping there, this creates a vector for abuse. But consider further - my co-worker bounties rep back to me. Their rep goes down, but their "rep counting towards privileges" stays the same. Meanwhile, my rep is back to where it was at the beginning, but now my "rep counting towards privileges" is permanently increased - and so is my co-worker's.

Comment: And if you make it so that receiving a bounty no longer impacts privileges in either direction, then all you've done is effectively remove bounties from the site.

Comment: If rep is a unit of trust, im not sure it follows that bounties should effect privileges in either direction. You're more trusted because you were given a bounty? But I agree with Joe and Grade that it could open up loopholes not previously thought of. In the example Grade gave, that would already be against the rules - however it becomes more of a problem I suppose. Perhaps when you award a bounty, it first comes out of your bounty-rep (which is hidden anyway). But then meh. Complexity for not a whole lot extra.

Comment: @J.J Well yes, the application of rep on a bounty is in some respects arbitrary, which is why some people (perhaps including yourself) believe bounties should not exist. Personally I appreciate that they provide a method of highlighting attention on specific questions, which is particularly useful in low-traffic tags. However all of that is really a debate on its own - "should bounties exist?" And is outside the specific context of this requested feature.