# What could cause a privilege to be revoked other than a loss of reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

A loss of reputation can cause a privilege to be revoked:

[Is it possible to lose a privilege if you lose the required reputation for it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267707/)

What could cause a privilege to be revoked other than a loss of reputation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, nothing. If you get suspended, you'll (temporarily) lose all privileges, but your reputation is set to 1 as well.

On beta sites, where the required reputation for most privileges is lower, you can lose privileges when the site graduates and the required reputation for privileges goes up. But Stack Overflow is way past that point.

It's not unthinkable of that some privilege levels are adjusted in the future because of misuse by low-reputation users. Two examples: tag creation on Stack Overflow requires [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), but only [300 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on other graduated sites in the network. Nominating yourself during a ♦ moderator election normally requires 300 reputation, but here it's 3000 reputation plus a handful of badges.

If you consider the ['dupehammer'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/4751173), the ability for gold tag badge holders to singlehandedly close a question in their tag as a duplicate, a privilege, you can lose that one if you don't fit the requirements anymore (1000 score in 200 answers) – this can happen because questions get retagged or posts get deleted.

@JonClements notes the [access review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege, which you can lose when you receive a [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension) (by failing enough review audits, or when doing enough poor reviews to get the attention of the moderators who can issue a review suspension manually). Chat-based privileges ([talk in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), [create chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) and [create gallery chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)) can be lost when you get a chat suspension (which can be issued independently of a main site suspension).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really insightful. The last part of your answer is interesting. I recently posted an answer on Stack Overflow which got downvoted for being too short and I lost some reputation. However, my reputation was restored after I deleted my answer. Does this mean earned reputation can be lost by deleting my upvoted answers and lost reputation can be regained by deleting my downvoted answers?

Comment: If one considers access to the review queues as a "privilege" (I admit - it's definitely a stretch) then failing audits or moderator imposed review bans can cause loss of access...

Comment: @COrNotToC yes, that's correct. (Do note that deleting enough posts can eventually lead to a post ban.)

Comment: Also you can lose the privilege to use chat even if you have 20+ rep to use it if you're "naughty"...

Comment: @JonClements well, they're all listed in the privilege list. Thanks for the additions.

Comment: On a side note: one can also lose the "create chat rooms" privilege independently of a chat suspension by having been kicked from chat a lot... (and that's permanent until lifted by a moderator manually)

Comment: @Glorfindel Unfortunately, I have recently lost the privilege of commenting everywhere after a question that I had answered got deleted. The question got deleted which caused my answer to get deleted which caused my reputation to decrease below 50 which caused me to lose the privilege of commenting everywhere. More information about this situation is available here: meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378678/6419919

Comment: That's sad, but it happens to all of us. But that counts as a 'loss of reputation' in my book.