# Is that bullying?

Tags: discussion

Well, I recently ran into a great question (at least what I consider great):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707059/looping-program-until-user-exits/26707268#26707268

By the time I finished writing up an answer for it, there already was an user sitting on the poster that his code doesn't run. While I get that his code sample is far from perfect, this isn't really a question of semantics, but a general idea how to resolve the problem, at least in my mind. Similarly he also followed with down voting my answer, citing his reasons as you can see in comment.

I got a bit agitated on the way he kept on picking on the code sample, so I've called him on it, as for me this is borderline bullying as it doesn't lead to anything constructive and is presented in rather harsh way.

Am I wrong on this one?

Comment: I don't think you will gain anything by continuing the argument. If you disagree with somebody on this site, IMHO it's best to clearly present your point of view once, in a professional way, and then walk. So one person does not like your answer, and nothing you say will change that. There are plenty of other people who can vote on it, and decide if they find it useful.

Comment: @RetoKoradi my point about bullying is not with the downvote, and I am not the target of it, but the barrage at OP because his code sample is less than ideal. And then when I've pressed on it he replied, and let me quote, "Its not whether I can figure out what the code is doing, is whether the asker can? They've not narrowed down the problem at all, and the question isn't good.". And yet doesn't give any reasons, other than code sample, why the question is bad.

Comment: *Bullying may be defined as the activity of* ***repeated, aggressive*** *behavior intended to hurt another person,* ***physically, mentally or emotionally.*** *Bullying is characterized by an individual behaving in a certain way to* ***gain power over*** *another person.* Telling someone their Python code is not indented correctly and will not run does not look like bullying to me.

Comment: It is not a great question.  The beginning of the answer has problems, too.  (And may the blessings of Roomba be upon it all!)  It is certainly tempting to judge the comments as unfriendly, but it is difficult to judge a lot of things online.  I had a more negative reaction to the beginning of the answer "With approach like that you are setting yourself for a lot of future abuse, which is not a good idea." and was sorely tempted to tone it down to "This is not a good approach. I'll try to explain why." and leave a note. But time is scarce, and I figured it wouldn't be appreciated.

Comment: @Paul actually any feedback is highly appreciated and I've reworked the first paragraph to something way more approachable. And we may disagree on a definition of a great question, but he does describe the problem and shows what he has done so far, which is great in my book.

Comment: @Puciek I'm glad you found my remark helpful.  In general, Stack Overflow is about technical Q&A and so it is best to refocus one's own and others' efforts in that direction.  One form of refocus is to leave most personal **comments** unacknowledged, flagging the worst ones for moderator attention. Inappropriate remarks in either questions or answers can be edited out, though this seems to be more common in questions (HELP! My code sucks but here it is.  THIS IS DUE TOMORROW!).

Comment: @Paul like remarks of sort "But time is scarce, and I figured it wouldn't be appreciated"?

Comment: Yeah, like that :-)  Most people don't like having their answers edited, but in your case perhaps I was incorrect.

Comment: @Paul well, now I am most curious about the closed vote, which mentions that it was closed because it is a "request for debugging", even though the OP says: "My only problem here is getting the menu to loop. You should not be allowed to choose option 2 or 3 before entering a filename via option 1.". It sounds a lot of like a feature request, rather than debugging to me, but I guess this is the price of bringing something to meta.

Comment: Well, the OP says the problem is "getting the menu to loop" and also a constraint about the order of options.  So we have a problem statement, we have some code.  But is the problem statement succinct, and the code the minimal code?  Not when there are reports that the code won't even run.  I also saw an improperly indented import, some strange use of parameters when defining a few functions.  Looks like a *can of worms*, that is, multiple issues.  The "on-hold" is just a time out for the OP to fix the question.

Comment: The way to ask 'how do I make a menu loop?' is to produce 5-10 lines of code, containing the minimum possible.  It could be a non-looping example, or a broken looping one, but nothing else.  No downloads from Yahoo, no singing bunnies (ok, he didn't have singing bunnies). Just menu and loop.

Comment: @Paul what should it contain if you have no idea how to turn it into a infinite loop? 5-10 lines of code containing what?

Comment: @Puciek Then put the code that is supposed to happen in each loop, and two comments `# begin loop ` and `# goto beginning` and explain you don't know what goes in those two spots.

Comment: @Paul like that? : inline `
    def loadmenu(): #I want this to loop
    print '''MAIN MENU
    =========
    1. Read portfolio
    2. Show current value
    3. Show change in value'''
    return int_input(0)`

I give up on trying to paste code in here in meaningful and readable way.

Comment: @Puciek Stack Overflow, and all the other stack sites, have a kind of *bait-and-switch* going on.  A lot of people think this is a place they can get their questions answered, or answer questions (thus helping others).  That's the *bait*.  But that's not the long term goal.  The goal, or the *switch* part is to build a library of good Q&A entries.  That's why there is so much filtering and regulation compared to other forums.  I've phrased this in the language of scams and ripoffs because people do feel ripped off when their time is wasted or question unanswered.... but help is a side effect..

Comment: @Paul there is a difference between filtering bad questions and closing a question because it is supposedly about debugging. And even the comments made by LegoStormtroopr there do not indicate that he doesn't understand what OP wants (or that he was any other issue with the question), just that his code sample doesn't work.

Comment: The message lists the **requirements for a debugging question**.  Debugging questions are clearly allowed.

Comment: The question is bad; there is zero effort from OP to clean things up or to provide a _minimal_ example or even any amount of code that can be copypasted and run as is. They just incorrectly pasted their whole code (which also requires an external file to run) and added a few comments. This is understandable to a degree as the user is new to SO, but that just makes it more important to close the question and introduce OP to SOs quality standards. And this certainly isn't "bullying" - I don't even see how the comments by Stormtrooper could be seen as rude, they're just not sugarcoated.

Comment: @l4mpi is that quality standard the reason why you didn't read all the comments here before replying? Because the op is not asking you to help him figure out why the script doesn't work, he asks HOW to add a feature to it.

Comment: @Puciek Please don't assume what I did and didn't read; in fact I read all of it. It's rather you who doesn't seem to be able to understand the arguments presented by Paul, me and the other users. Fact is, in the process of asking "How" OP pastes a whole lot of unneccessary code, which makes everything else about the question almost irrelevant. The usual approach to a SO question like this should be OP trying something, running into a _specific_ problem, and presenting a minimal example demonstrating the problem. Not pasting all of the code and saying "now I want to add X, how do I do that".

Comment: @l4mpi the code in this question is actually irrelevant, the question asked in first 3 lines is that general and simple. He did work on something, he did run into a problem he didn't know how to solve, and some guy jumped on him and "wasn't sugarcoating". This wasn't a case where he posted a code and said "fix me", he descirbed his problem and posted what he was working with.

Comment: It is bullying, yes.  You are trying to shut-up an SO user that's assisting the OP in creating a better question.  Please refrain from doing so, it is not constructive.

Comment: And in the process of doing so, OP posts a whole lot of irrelevant code for people to sift through and figure out if there's any approach from OP which should be taken into consideration. I don't know what you're trying to argue here, it's not that the question is completely unanswerable but that it is far from clean and unneccessarily raises the hurdle to answering it. It's simply _not a good question_. The fact that all of the code is actually irrelevant (your words!) should be a very strong indicator for this.

Comment: Are you trying to shut me up?  You need to direct your comment to the OP, I just use the term in a similar way he used it in his question.

Comment: I just laid back couple hours ago and enjoy the "show", where my just dreadful answer gathered now 4 downvotes and enough comments to write a book. And yet, not single of this people who are do deeply concerned about quality of my answer, actually went there to post the "correct way to do it". Even though the question was re-opened hours ago. Just so you know, I won't be deleting a perfectly good answer just because I get cross-stack down votes.

Comment: There is obviously bullying on SO.

Comment: @TrevorOakley hey again! Seriously, I can see how you can feel this is what's happening on SO... Try to open your mind a bit and see the broader picture. FB sent you here without telling you what our quality standards are. We maintain our quality standards.... that's not bullying. The bullying would be FB sending users our way with bad questions. It creates a terrible experience for you, with which I do sympathize. But I see no reason to change our ways for FB

Comment: I am using this link for my referral - http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/facebook-developer-forums-stack-overflow/267497 In fact from my two posts about FB it is clear people here do not understand FB integration. The issue with being self-serving is that you shoud not influence others but confine yourselves to each other. You tell eachother it is high quality but it clearly is not. I have seen countless wrong answers. You need to drop the FB link immediately and then you can all be  self-serving to eachother saying how good you all are and delete any criticism.

Comment: @TrevorOakley That partnership **was dropped**, years ago! Largely because of the issue at play here: Facebook kept directing people to make posts here that violated our community standards, and Facebook was too cheap and lazy to provide any support by themselves. That post is about the `facebook.stackoverflow.com` subdomain, which no longer exists. There is no partnership any more, but Facebook continues to divert people here as part of their general neglect of developer support. Yell at them all you want -- they certainly deserve it.

Comment: @TrevorOakley (one last try). If stack is of so poor quality... why is it and does it remain the top indexed site and the reference for Q&A sites? Not saying it's perfect, but for the scale it has, it's of pretty solid quality. Are there wrong answers? yes, of course. Most downvoted, some unfortunately not. In any way, as a Q&A site, it decided on certain formats for its questions. We're happy to help out, on virtually any topic... that abides to that. Make your FB question follow the rules. SERIOUSLY, it'll be worth it. Stack is just a tool like any other site... use it properly, it'll work.

Comment: In answer to the comment about the SO/FB connection being dropped, I googled developer facebook forum initially to find the right forum and aside from the facebook site and a conference ad, the top few all were at SO and several articles referred to SO in official partner terms. I tried to find other forums but could not and I kept seeing references to SO. When I posted a question in SO about the FB SDK it got all minus votes and my comments got deleted - several times. It was that and also the fact I saw countless posts with recommendations that prompted this post.

Comment: @TrevorOakley which is what I referred to saying "it creates a terrible user experience for you, which I sympathize with". Unfortunately, Stack doesn't see the need to bend its quality standards because of outside pressure. If your questions about the FB SDK are on topic, they won't be downvoted. Asking for libraries and off-site ressources (which your questions were doing) is off-topic. Period. FB SDK or no FB SDK. Post a very specific question about how to use the SDK, make it on topic.... it'll get a good reception :)

Comment: Just on the last point about outside pressure, you will see changes in the future. I know twitter has intense political pressure on it to change in the UK, and there is now a significant movement to regulate web companies engaged in social media. Speech is regulated. The web issue always how to regulate something which has no physical presence - jurisdiction question? For the lawyers this has been a huge issue which has seen extensive legal work. When the jurisdiction issue is resolved you will see more regulation come quickly over web companies. There are many legal aspects to this.

Comment: @TrevorOakley we'll see... in the meantime, I suggest you stick to our guidelines and rules if you want your questions to have good reception. Stack never really bent to outside pressure, and I don't see it starting now. Stack became THE reference because of its quality standards. Now that it's a reference, people see it as a helpdesk. Maybe it'll change in the future. I'd be surprised though, as I don't see which kind of law Stack may have broken by sticking to the standards explained and available to you. Anyway.... I don't see this getting anywhere. If you want to change your ways, cool...

Comment: @TrevorOakley if not, I would just say be careful as the system CAN and WILL eventually ban you if you get too many bad questions. This isn't a threat, just a warning that it might happen on your account. Read the help center, abide by the guidelines there :).

Comment: Also regulators can close down the whole site and prosecute contributors. That is a warning.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is absolutely no bullying here. In particular, the comments on your answer are calm and strictly technical responses to your [request for a downvote explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Your first response is a rather prickly; I would recommend that if you cannot respond in kind to a straightforward technical critique of your posts that you refrain from saying anything. Barking at people who take a moment to explain their view of problems with your answer [will, over time, lead to fewer people being willing to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question/250182?s=1|0.1152#250182).

The comments on the question may read as perhaps a shade less congenial, but still just point out specific problems with the post.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Note especially that when Lego Stormtroopr talks about a "self-contained example", that's because such a thing has [an entire dedicated page in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and is [particularly called out in one of our closure reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/257887#257887) -- which is, as of this writing, the reason that's been selected for this question by all four of the close voters.

Comment: Some telling me to refrain from self expression needs to apply their comments to themselves. That person is not entitled to tell me anything.

Answer (score -1):

The lesson to learn here is this:

```
@downvoter - care to explain the reason for it?
```

Is never constructive!

Comment: But even [Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592113/c-how-to-split-list-based-on-index#comment6365009_5592133) [Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287590/how-to-gettype-of-liststring-in-c#comment3403712_3287629) [does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995038/how-do-i-declare-a-method-in-c-cli-that-will-be-seen-as-an-extension-method-in#comment3398026_995154) [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409969/polymorphism-define-in-just-two-sentences#comment4878683_409982) (did it?).

Comment: It's not hard at all to come up with a polite request that downvoters explain why they downvoted or give suggestions to improve the downvoted post (e.g "@downvoter Could you tell me what part of this question is unclear so that I can clarify it?"). What made you come to the conclusion that "Could you explain your downvote" comments are never constructive?