# What is wrong with this question, and how to eliminate improper down-voting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

Just recently [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246977/how-do-native-libraries-affect-device-support) was down-voted.  I posted this quite a long time ago.  I feel that it was a valid question.  I presented a problem and asked a specific question.  I did research before posting, but did not indicate so.

I am not so concerned with the loss of rep.  I do want to understand what I did wrong however.  I have read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and do not think that I have deviated from the guidelines.  Could someone please help me to understand this?

---

This also makes me think that it is too easy to down-vote.  I often see that questions are down-voted without any explanation from the down-voter.  This does not help the OP understand what they did wrong.  Earlier tonight, I saw this behavior on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371679/can-i-open-a-genymotion-device-from-a-terminal-command?noredirect=1#comment43194843_27371679).  The question was valid, but a variation of it had been asked before.  It is a shame that the down-voter did not point this out.

So, is it too easy to down-vote?

- Perhaps comments should be required when down-voting?
- Perhaps a higher rep should be required - currently I think it is only 125.

Comment: Nice.  A down-vote without a comment.  :-)

Comment: Canonical reference for the once-a-week question about requiring comments for downvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes . See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question , from yesterday: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278664/require-anonymous-commenting-or-upvote-of-existing-comment-before-downvoting-or , and on and on.

Comment: Fair enough, but this was not a "once-a-week question about requiring comments for down votes".  That was just one of two suggestions. Shame on me for not searching on this.  However I also (a) posted another suggestion, (b) initially asked what was wrong with a specific question.

Comment: It's a single downvote, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Sometimes people [lose their keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Comment: I'm not worried about a single down-vote, just trying to understand what I can do to improve and what are the expectations of StackOverflow.

Comment: That "lose their keys" link is good BTW.

Comment: `what I can do to improve and what are the expectations of StackOverflow`? With **236 posts** on Stack Overflow and **only 1 posts with a negative score**, you seem to be already on top of expectations, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't downvote, and don't have the mind reading skills to know why somebody did. But if you're interested in concerns that people *might* have with the question, I see a couple:

- When I started reading the question, it sounded like you were going to ask for a library recommendation. Which I'm sure you're well aware is Off Topic. The first couple of paragraphs, you're describing how you're considering a library, but aren't sure if it's a good choice. The question ends up taking a different turn, but you can't count on everybody reading the whole thing.
- The question is overall somewhat vague. What is "many devices" for you? And what's a "vast majority"? It's not clear how a good answer for this question would look.
- At least in the strict sense, somebody could argue that it's not a programming question, and is therefore not a good fit for SO. It's more about the market share of different CPU architectures.

But in the big picture, I completely agree with what @AzizShaikh said in a comment. Based on the record you have with your questions and answers, I think you're doing just fine. While it's great to have high standards, and wanting every question/answer to be a success, there's no reason to worry too much about one question that gets one downvote.