# Is there any monitoring of users that just downvote for no reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some users just downvote for no reason,

1. Is there any monitoring of that kind of behavior?
2. If a user downvotes some answers more than once for the same user in a very short period of time, is there any kind of moderation for that?

this kind of behavior reduces Stack Overflow's quality in my opinion.

I even have accepted answers with negative score, if someone thinks the answer is not good enough, why don't they post their own? Is it because the are only interested in reputation points?

Some of Stack Overflow's answers have been very useful to me, and I think that if now it's my turn to contribute to it, I have to do it with respect and responsability.

And why isn't there any obligation to leave at least an anonymous comment on why the downvote? It could help the poster and the readers who have no Idea why the answer has negative score. The downvoter might be wrong. So if the comment is mandatory it would reveal the point of view of the downvoter without revealing their identity.

**Note**: As a side note, I also have a feature request. It would be great if there was a minimum time during which answers are not postable, just to prevent some posters who write any thing just to be the first to answer.

Comment: Egregious serial downvoting will be reversed automatically within 24 hours.  Requiring comments for downvotes has been brought up many times and soundly rejected.  There already is a delay (15 minutes?) before an answer can be accepted.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I didn't mean for the answer to be accepted, but for it to be posted.

Comment: "if someone thinks the answer is not good enough, why don't they post their own? Is it because the are only interested in reputation points?" If a person is only interested in their own rep, then downvoting an answer is counterproductive.

Comment: WHy don't I post an answer instead of downvoting-  sometimes I do.  Sometimes I don't have time.  Sometimes I don't know the answer, but know you're wrong (for example you don't answer the question).  Sometimes someone else has posted a much better answer already.  Plenty of reasons why I may downvote without answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Targeted* voting (what you describe as multiple downvotes against a single user in a short time) is already handled by the serial-vote detection script.

Comments are not required for numerous reasons already discussed on Meta, for example, here: [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question)

Note also that an answer being *accepted* doesn't necessarily mean that its of high quality, it just means that the OP liked it the most (ideally that it helped him the most). There are *many* negatively scored accepted answers on the site. Perhaps the downvoters just didn't feel like the post was worth putting together a better answer for.

I don't see much benefit in putting a "no answer" period, as everyone would race-post as soon as the timeout expired. So no one wins FGITW, but you just get people smashing the button to get it in as soon as possible, does that really fix anything?

Comment: How many downvotes would be considered `Targeted` voting?

Comment: @iharob No one knows, the algorithm is a secret. Suffice it to say that its more than a few, and less than a lot.