# Finding Down Voting Reasons

Tags: support

If we know the reason for down voting, we may prevent the mistakes , Do we have any options for find the reason?

Comment: Generally, slovenly or non-existing formatting/grammar lead to downvotes, too.

Comment: Looking at your latest downvoted post, you'd do yourself some good if you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You already know the reasons probably, you're just going ahead and making the mistakes anyway. I don't mean that in a sarcastic way - most people overrule what is right with what they desperately need.

Comment: I'm very new to stack overflow, i just try to understand the process, it's making lot of confusion..

Comment: If you're talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827073/how-to-do-jquery-bootgrid-table-grouping), you may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've not found any great problem with finding reasons to downvote.  I find it quite easy.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that post, but it is a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question).

Comment: Thanks Guys now i may able to understand process well from reading your answers and posts. Now only noticed 21 down vote for this question , its okay,it will be example to users who is really a new to stack overflow. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Exactly why a user voted the way they did is known only to them unless they decide to add a comment explaining what they think is wrong with the post. Also just because someone comments doesn't mean they also down-voted.

The general guidance of the tooltip "This answer is not useful" or "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is all you have.

Comment: And of course even if there is a comment, that doesn't necessarily  mean they're the downvoter, or that's the exact reason.

Comment: I think it should be a prerequisite that if you down vote you must provide a reason. I've had two completely inexplicable down votes today and I'm none the wiser for what the problem was. Crazy.

Answer (score 10):

Read the tool tip.  It explains the reasons for downvoting a post.

Comment: Not everyone down votes for the reason given in that tool tip, knowing why someone down voted you would be useful.

Comment: @StrategyThinker And yet the tooltip is what you have.  Anything beyond that is just speculation.

Comment: The tooltip is the best guess that you have, but it is not guaranteed to be the reason for the down vote.