# Why isn't there "vote to improve" option for questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We usually vote to close questions which are "too broad" or just ask the SO to improve it after putting it on hold but why no "Vote to improve button" which says "5 users say you must improve your question (or **give suggestions to improve**?)"

Questions which may seem too broad to a few users may not actually be too broad.
The OP might actually be looking at a specific aspect but may have missed to mention it in the question.

Example : "Which is better Functional Programming vs Imperative Programming?"

But maybe the OP meant "Is functional programming better than Imperative Programming for transformations in XLST?"

This has multiple views but I feel such question should be encouraged so that there is a healthy discussion to share & learn more.

> A "vote to improve" option where a User may specify the changes which maybe done so as to improve the OP's question.

This also helps reduce anonymous down-votes. I have often seen anonymous down-votes to questions by newer users. Also refer : [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/2142994)

If the question was edited appropriately, the question could be very useful. Don't you all think so?

Comment: Use a better sample of your concern please. How on earth is _""Is functional programming better in Python or Java?""_ less broad or opinion based than _"Which is better Python or Java?"_ actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay.

Comment: We do!  It's called the downvote button.

Comment: @Will Yes but a down-vote may not even be justified by the voter!
A "vote to improve" option where a User may specify the changes which maybe done so as to improve the question.

Comment: @AniMenon If you're asserting that the question needs to be improved for it to be a good question, then it follows that it's not *currently* a good question, meaning it most likely merits a downvote.

Comment: @Servy Most Likely yes, but there is a chance that one of the **users feels the question is right & tries to answer** but the question just goes *on hold* since *many others felt the question is inappropriate*.

Comment: @AniMenon That's radically different from what you were saying; you were saying that someone would see a question, feel that it needs to be improved before it can be answered, and want a way to "vote for it to be improved"; in response to being told that you should downvote in such situations, you've asserted that such a question may not be justified, even though that person *feels that the question needs to be improved before it can be answered*, meaning they feel that the question is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: @Servy Its unanswerable in the current state but "vote to improve" rather than saying `we cannot answer this` says `you may improve like this`.
Your point is very valid for a question which is too broad or out of context and can't be improved. But sometimes minor improvements may make a question look more answerable(needless to say not all users may feel the same).

Comment: @AniMenon If a question is inappropriate in its current state but could be improved, then the appropriate tools are to downvote and close vote.  It would be inappropriate to vote to *delete* a question you felt could be improved.

Comment: `This also helps reduce anonymous down-votes` you say that like it's desirable?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for is an anti-close vote, that has the same purpose as close voting, which is weird.

Comment: @KevinB No I am asking for a place where users may provide suggestions to improve a question.

Comment: Oh, so like comments

Comment: @KevinB Exactly. When a question goes to on-hold (which happens very often with new users), the OP may not know how to improve his/her question.

Comment: right. so... leave a comment on said closed question then. questions can be commented on until they are deleted.

Comment: @KevinB That maybe done but what I am saying is why not given option where a user can say *Vote to improve- syntax* or *Vote to improve- formatting*?

Comment: Isn't that what the "Edit" button is for?

Comment: @TZHX Edit is to make changes not to suggest a change to the OP. I was thinking of an option where a user can say, *you may improve it this way*.

Comment: Comments are a good way to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> why no "Vote to improve button" which says "5 users say you must improve your question

That's exactly what voting to close *does*.  It's telling the author that his question isn't appropriate as it sits; it explains why, and tells him that he needs to edit it into an appropriate question in order for it to be reopened.

> Questions which may seem too broad to a few users may not actually be too broad.

If others disagree, they can vote to reopen the question.

> The OP might actually be looking at a specific aspect but may have missed to mention it in the question.

Then it's important that the question be closed until he can edit the question into that more specific question that he's *actually* interested in.

> Example : "Which is better Python or Java?"
>
> But maybe the OP meant "Is functional programming better in Python or Java?"

That's going to be an opinion based question, as well as being too broad, and wouldn't belong on SO, even after the edit.

> This has multiple views but I feel such question should be encouraged so that there is a healthy discussion to share & learn more.

Then you're on the wrong site.  This isn't the type of question SO wants to have; we're not looking for open ended discussions.  You should be looking to other sites for such activities.

> If the question was edited appropriately, the question could be very useful. Don't you all think so?

The example you gave?  No, I see no way for that to be edited into a question that would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My example was inappropriate.