# Is 'downvoting' being inspected?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Actually, I have searched for half an hour for a similar question. Sorry if there exists exactly the same but I haven't managed to find it.

Is downvoting **really** being inspected?

I feel like a lot of clear questions and answers are being downvoted unrighteously.

Most of the times I check newest questions here for a while on a specific time of the day, I notice that a downvote raid is going on by clearly **random** reasons which are not even being told to owners of the posts.
If there's something to be downvoted, at least it has to be said and stated publicly rather than being done in 'hmm, downvote' style.

Once again, is downvoting really being inspected?

Comment: The only rule on voting is that you can't downvote people, only content. Different people have different opinions and what you see is unrighteous someone else may think is completely righteous. No we're not going to enforce comments.

Comment: Enforcing comments is out of option but, what's the idea of keeping downvote reason as a secret? If the idea is wrong, there should be a way to improve it to a common point which anyone who does mistakes would like to hear

Comment: Do you think it's unrighteous that you're getting downvotes on this question itself? Have you noticed the downvote tooltip gives a possible reason as being lack of research. Do you think this post shows any prior research given that variants of this question are asked daily and none of those previous discussions have been referenced here?

Comment: The downvote reason is not secret it's right there on the downvote tooltip for all to see.

Comment: It's not a personal question as you might misunderstood by dealing with a lot of questions like this(?). This question is about the useful content which might help people being downvoted without any alternative solutions

Comment: Why don't you read some of those previous questions and their answers before posting this one then and save the rest of us some time reading the same thing day after day?

Comment: I did read them, none of them were asking this question clearly (as i stated in my post)

Comment: 'I feel like a lot of clear questions and answers are being downvoted unrighteously' - don't care about what you 'feel' - evidence please.  Please cite examples of unjustified downvoting.  Note that the other dozens of posters with similar complaint/s could not come up with a single example.  Maybe you can  do better?

Comment: @Robert Longson After half an hour of a research, I wasn't able to find the question that's linked here. The reason might be the downvotes since it reduces the priority  to be seem. Also when you go to the root question, it's not still asking the same question as here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question

Comment: ' I notice that a downvote raid is going on by clearly random reasons which are not even being told to owners of the posts' - that claim is internally inconsistent.

Comment: I haven't taken notes, or evidence. All i've seen was there were a lot of clean contents that are downvoted without alternative solutions which could help asker or answerer.

Comment: I will agree that there is a certain amount of 'randomness' when it comes down to close vote reasons for some questions.  It is against SO 'be nice' policy to use a custom close reason of 'this question is complete rubbish', even if it is.  Contributors therefore just pick 'unclear' or 'too broad', dependig on moon phase.

Comment: 'I haven't taken notes, or evidence', not a surprise.  That means: 'I've actually got nothing', same as all the other 'hostile mobs downvoting for no good reason' posts here.

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered to type on meta.stackoverflow if I didn't have anything. I have seen enough, but I don't have any 'evidence' for people to read this question objectively.

Comment: I think not enough questions and answers are down voted. I can back my claim by the many [bad review audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) meta posts that are 9 out of 10 caused by up votes on posts that seasoned reviewers and experienced users on SO qualify as bad. If I have to comment on everything for users that didn't spend a minute on understanding what SO is about, I need another 24 hours in my day. And I probably end-up arguing why I'm the bad flower and the OP is brilliant.

Comment: @BurakDay you've got 'nuthin.  I, OTOH, have a large list of links to truly apalling questions from clueless beginners, incompetents, deadbeats and liars, all trying to get other SO users to do all their work for them without lifting a single mouse-click themselves, or issuing grossly multi-duped trivia for their sockpuppets and/or voting-ring members to answer and  upvote.

Comment: Against that mass of abuse, the odd one or two downvotes that might be unjustified is just below the noise level.  You cannot give examples because you cannot filter any of them out from the background of trash.

Comment: @MartinJames By 'you' meaning the SE?

Comment: No Burak... He means YOU can't find good posts with downvotes (the implication being there aren't any). You have to understand... This topic comes to meta maybe weekly. No one can EVER show us good posts that are downvoted, but taking a quick tour to the new questions page,you can find a PILE of shit in seconds.... so i don't see the problem, I've personally never seen "downvote raids"...

Comment: Allright Patrice, i will accept what i'have seen as 'odd one or two downvotes that might be unjustified below the noise level' then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So don't get me wrong... I'm not saying it NEVER happens (im realizing this is how my other message sounds). But normally people who come and complain about unjustified downvotes simply don't get Stack. With a different vision of the goal of the site, the vision on quality surely changes as well

Comment: Unfortunately, for every question poster that has the IQ of a mooring cleat, the comprehension of a coconut and the willingness of a zombified sloth, there are nine others who just want to take you, and any other SO users who are naive enough to reply,  for every drop of blood they can get.

Comment: @MartinJames that's a bit unfair, at least mooring cleats solve a problem.

Comment: Half the stuff on the first five pages this morning (aka four hours ago) was utter crap.  Questions that were nothing but a poorly detailed requirement and an appeal for someone to code it for them.  I downvoted every single one of them.  Cackled while I did it, too.

Comment: There's a lot of talk here about lack of examples of decent answers that were downvoted.  I recently answered a question (at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684686/cant-include-state-machine-in-module/37685228#37685228).  When I saw it was downvoted, my reaction was 'huh? I thought it was good; if it's not I'd like to understand why'.  But as I understand it (and I'm relatively new to active participation in SO), there is no way I can contact the voter or answer that question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

People can downvote for almost any reason they like to.

What people can't do is mass-vote on specific users. You should vote on content, not on the users posting it.

But yes, outside of that (which is checked both by moderators pattern recognition skills and a secret algorithm SE has to detect it) people are free to vote as they please, and they don't have to disclose the reasons.

Comment: Without explaining why he did that, the community can't improve their answers or questions...

Comment: @RonaldoFelipe Our voting system is a quality control mechanism. It signals other users whats worth their time and what isn't. A downvote in and of itself carries a reason too. If you hover over the downvote, it says "This answer is not useful" or "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Thats all the reasoning you need.

Comment: is it true, even though the comments section may helped someone?

Comment: Shouldn't an alternative solution must be given after a downvote in order to make people correct their mistakes?

Comment: @BurakDay suggested before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question

Comment: @BurakDay there already is - the user can read the help, tour and examples.  That works even better if they bother to take all the help they can find BEFORE posting their hopeless, no-effort homework dumps.

Comment: @RonaldoFelipe - Requiring a comment for downvotes is something that has been declined roughly once a week for years. It's a bad idea because a) you'd just get people posting gibberish to be able to downvote something, b) it would discourage downvotes on absolute trash, reducing the quality of the site, and c) would lead to a lot more personal retaliation by those being downvoted. There are good reasons for making voting anonymous, and targeted voting against individuals is handled quietly behind the scenes.

Comment: @MartinJames you shouldn't classify people since not only 'hopeless homework solution seekers' ask question. Also, first-hand help is always better than taking a tour.

Comment: @BurakDay Its also more exhausting and more frustrating for the people providing the help. This site has a [tour] for a reason use it.

Comment: @Burak.... What happens is that people join the site, ser the quick feedback loop, come to meta with all the best intentions, like you. Start really working on helping new users post and learn the site. The fourth or fifth time you get insulted, trash-talked, and serially downvoted for not giving them their answer NOW..... you'll see otherwise. I remember that's how i started....

Comment: @Patrice I totally understand your point and agree with it. I was trying to talk about the useful questions or answers which are not coming from starters but the owners that spent time for it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Burak but see... The problem is that without specific examples it's hard to judge if we are on the same quality level when it comes down to posts. Sometimes we see these posts on meta like yours, then we see example posts, and the first answer is "those are off topic as per the help center". Its hard to say "yeah the useful questions that are downvoted shouldn't" when we have no proof that this happens...