# Why can questions be set for review and then deleted without voters justification?

Tags: discussion

I seen certain questions on Stack Overflow being set for review and then closed, or even deleted without most reviewers or any at all giving justification to the asker for their vote. A newbie can be shocked by this practice, which gives no way out.

What incentives do people have on Stack Overflow to close, delete, or reopen edited questions?

Why are down, review, close and delete votes without providing at least one verifiable by asker justification or link to substantiate such action, even anonymous, allowed on Stack Overflow?

Comment: actually downvoting reduces your reputation

Comment: @SamIam Only downvotes on answers.

Comment: There is no reputation to be gained from voting of any kind on other user's content.

Comment: Delete votes are only accessible at 10k, or even 20k for trying to delete answers.

Comment: Exactly same practice is observed in this thread. Instead of providing a reasonable explanation to such obscure policy, the question is downvoted aimed to hide it from the public without any explanation whatsoever in any formal answer.

Comment: -1 for lack of general research.  A lot of the claims you make in your question are not true.

Comment: I said it on your last question, I'll say it again. You should really learn more about how the site works before assigning malicious intent to others.

Comment: Related: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: Almost dupe: [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/1026459)

Comment: It seems like this question and your last one are based on misunderstandings of how the site works, with this one full of incorrect statements about the way things work here. I sincerely suggest you go check out the [help] and read through some things there. I also suggest checking out the [FAQs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) here on Meta.

Comment: One thing we encourage all users to provide when discussing things on Meta is **objective proof** to back up opinions about how the site works. Objective proof *can* be anecdotal, but we prefer actual data from, for example, [Data.se](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), which can query all of the data in Stack Overflow. If you can find a pattern of deletion "without verifiable justification or link", that would signal a problem.

Comment: @Travis Thanks for the links. I quickly looked through, and its hard to see justification for this policy other than "too many questions, too little time and resources to clean". But its a sensitive point for those affected, I know on my own experience, no stats needed.

Comment: @Mike I'm trying, you see this here and now. :) Linking generic Help points isn't enough to explain many common practices affecting large number of people.

Comment: I'm not entirely happy about the site's deletion policies either - but why are you giving the sensitivity of some users automatically, inherently more value than to the site's overall well-being?

Comment: Then you will likely continue to get negative feedback... You are asking for more justification than the documented manner in which the site was created, and yet provide no more justification for changing that than "people are sensitive".

Comment: @Pekka There are no questions without askers. They are paramount, not questions. Today's asker is tomorrow's answerer. I agree with many, anonymous verifiable justification of at least 1st close or delete vote MUST be required to give every person a way out. It can't possibly negatively affect the site in any way.

Comment: There is no **site** without answers and the people who give them. If you want a bunch of people asking and answering questions without any rules, go to Yahoo! Answers. The reason people flock to this site is that there are experts willing to *volunteer* their time to answer questions. If you can't respect their time, there's really not much more to discuss.

Comment: @Mike I don't see how your last comment is related to this thread's topic? Where did you get such generalization from - definitely not related to my posts. Are you claiming that everyone placing closing vote is an expert, and they refuse to provide a verifiable answer to save their time, by showing blatant disregard to the asker who are about the same human being as they are, and may have spent significant time to research and post the question or answer? No questions or answers needed on any site, except for humans, they're paramount.

Comment: One main problem is that you are asking a question here (and the other question you asked) which has been addressed countless times. The topics "let new users comment" and "comment with a downvote" are all over the place here. Just one minute of searching would have found more discussion on the topic than an hours worth of reading. And yet, we are left with this. Now you are switching into which is of more value, questioners versus answerers? This reads almost as trolling at this point.

Comment: You said "[t]here are no questions without askers. They are paramount...". I'm saying that answerers are more important than askers. If you have a site with only askers, you have a site with a lot of questions with no answers.

Comment: Answerers are much more rare, and much more valuable, than askers, though (within the context of a Q&A site). There is a near-unlimited supply of questions, but a very limited supply of good answers. That's just the way it is.

Comment: As has been said many times, you cannot delete a question without closing it first, and every question closed has a justification. Most questions are closed by votes by more than one person, each of which is a verification of the justification.

Comment: I'm talking about verification that an asker can do to see objective grounds for closure and possibly fix the question.

Comment: @Travis I always do some search before asking about anything, and also provide answers on several sites. The fact that nothing was done to change this policy can't prevent people to request its changed over and over again. Its not trolling to voice your objective needs. I do need at least one verifiable explanation for any question or answer closed, and it can't be "unclear" reason, since I can explain myself very clear.

Comment: As I said on [your question the other day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328105/permanently-cancelling-a-question-review), "set for review" **is not a thing**. People browse, they look at questions, and they vote on what they see. There's no star chamber where a cabal of high-rep users are crushing dissent to their iron-fisted rule of the site.

Comment: **Every down vote comes with all the explanation that should be expected and is deserved, it is right there on the down vote arrow**. It plainly states; *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. That is all you should expect to get, people need to quit complaining about down votes and spend the energy and time reading on how to ask better questions.

Comment: Before complaining you should do a better job understanding how things actually work, start by reading the Help Center over and over until you "get it". [Voting is anonymous for a very valid reason!](/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive)

Comment: This question is now closed by 5 voters and I'm sorry for the answers and comments but your post is so misguided that it might give the wrong information to users that do come to meta to learn or educate themselves about how the site works. I cast the final delete vote.

Answer (score 19):

Only moderators can delete questions that aren't closed, and they will only do so under extreme circumstances (typically spam or other highly inappropriate content).

For regular users voting to close a question, or any automated cleanup of questions, the question needs to have been closed, and for a question to be closed, a reason must be provided as to why it should be closed.

> Given the fact each vote gives extra reps, some feel casting 50 neg votes a day

The vote limit is 40 per day, not 50.

> [...] in 3 min without reading the questions or providing verifiable reason for Delete vote is the convenient way to gain rep fast.

You have no basis for asserting that people aren't reading the questions when they downvote them.

Additionally they aren't earning rep by downvoting bad questions, they're just making the world a better place by providing a better signal to others on the quality of the post.  It's an altruistic act.

Comment: "The vote limit is 40 per day" and even that limit is only reached by voting on 10 questions first, if you don't vote on questions then the limit is 30.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, some "reasons" are given in my limited understanding by the system instead of being given by people who voted. For example, any question can be labelled as "unclear" that basically presumes no formal justification is required. I seen this particular reason abused. Generally, if a question or answer is not "offensive" or absolutely stupid, the person deserves verifiable explanation from everyone who voted to close it.

Comment: @sambul35 what other justification you want? If it's unclear then the user is encouraged to edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: That's the loophole that allows malicious intent, and it should be compensated by requiring reasonable explanation from everyone who voted to close. If I don't like your question or answer for whatever reason, its far insufficient ground to remove it by simply claiming "its unclear".

Comment: @Braiam The premise of this question here is that people are voting on all questions; he's complaining about bad questions being downvoted.

Comment: @sambul35 You *are* getting a verifiable explanation from the people that voted to close.  Your claim that you don't like their explanation doesn't change the fact that they've given one.

Comment: @sambul35 That's why it takes 5 votes to close a question, and it can be reopened easily enough if others disagree with the close reason.  One person trying to close a question as unclear that most readers feel is perfectly clear does nothing.

Comment: "bad questions being downvoted." Correct me if I'm wrong but... that's not what it is supposed to happen?

Comment: @Servy If rep isn't gained by closing questions as per cited rules, why there's a limit of 40 per day for such activity? :)

Comment: @Servy "_It's an altruistic act._" Really, even when supplement by total disregard to the asker? Imaging, may be a question asked is of interest to many. Now what? Who will appreciate such altruism? No question - no answer. No explanation - no chance to improve. Yet another example: what if the voter has no idea how to answer the question or what's it about? Still can close without explanation that would reveal total luck of competence?

Comment: You must be actively disregarding the help topics and information you have been given. @Servy said that it takes 5 votes to close a question. So it would take 5 voters who "ha[ve] no idea how to answer the question" to close it. Additionally, there is an explanation (as has been noted time and again). So "No explanation" -- demonstrably untrue. After the question has been closed, it goes into an "on hold" state, wherein the user not only can, but is encouraged to, improve it. So "no chance to improve" -- demonstrably untrue. You're not doing yourself any favors by repeating incorrect info.

Comment: I had some of my code related questions and answers closed without verifiable explanation by 5 voters. Without knowing how to satisfy their needs, I tried blindly to edit them. However, the changed answers didn't draw any attention, no movement at all. It seems, the incentive to close, whatever it is, is higher than to review corrected answer and vote on it. So effectively the "edit" policy didn't work as expected. That means "no chance to improve". And "unclear" cliche is not an explanation from a living human without details.

Comment: @Samul35 - **you can edit your questions regardless if they are closed or not to improve them and try and get them reopened.** if you don't want to take the time to do that, then that is your bad, not ours, maybe if you took more time with them in the first place, read the help on how to ask a good question and spent some more effort in the beginning you would not be complaining about down votes and close votes at all.

Comment: @sambul35 "I had some of my code related questions and answers closed" - where **some** appears to be **1**. After your edit the question was reviewed and people voted to leave it closed. That means that your "clarification" did **not** make the question any clearer.

Comment: @sambul35 The only incentive there is, to close questions, is the incentive to improve the quality of the site.  There is monetary incentive, rep or otherwise.

Comment: Why most folks concentrate on closing questions, but not on re-opening the edited questions, despite queue of edited questions is much shorter? Is it because voters are afraid of retaliation from those who previously closed the question? This seems to be a clear trend. Theoretically its possible to edit and then re-open a question. But practically, no matter how much edit have you done, the question will not be re-open in my observation, unless by the same people who closed it, and that means "never" because you need 5 votes. So the only "real" way to re-open a question is to ask a mod.

Comment: It looks like the site will benefit from adding voters an incentive to review and re-open edited questions like +2 rep. Otherwise previously not engaged in that discussion voters ignore edited questions regardless of how well it was edited.

Comment: @sambul35 I'd like to see some hard evidence of this observation; graphs of data, for that matter.  Just because your questions have not been reopened, does not mean the same is true for every other question out there.  You don't even have the required rep to view the review queues, so where is this data coming from?

Comment: @sambul35 Questions don't often get reopened when edited because it's rather rare for the edits to actually fix the problems with the question that got it closed in the first place.  Going in and fixing a few grammar or formatting mistakes isn't going to make a quesiton that's too broad sufficiently narrow, or add clarity to an unclear question.  Really fixing these problems is hard, and most people either can't do it or aren't willing to put the time in to really do it properly.  When closed questions truly fix the problems and become good questions, they get reopened.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. But it doesn't correlate with my experience. Even when my questions on Meta were almost fully reworded by me, and then edited by other folks with high rep, which I appreciate as an effort to help re-open them, they in fact were never re-open, likely due to the fact they addressed some policy change proposals on this site many high rep folks viewed as threatening to the way they now raise rep, and don't want regular users to read and upvote these. This is on Meta, but on SO I see a similar trend, likely for a different reason that I posted above.

Comment: @sambul35 That sounds entirely consistent with my explanation.  Someone spending a lot of time improving the grammar, formatting, presentation, etc. of a post isn't fixing the kinds of core problems that get a question closed.  It's a very useful step towards making the question better, but in most cases *you* as the author, are the only one capable of fixing the core problems that would get a question closed.  That you haven't done so, and have left it to others, would explain why they're not getting reopened.  I could be more specific if you provided an example, of course.

Comment: @Servy OK, I got it. To get the question reopen, I'd need to remove the underlying cause for voters concern. And if the question is about changing the site policy that would affect these voters, they will never reopen it unless I remove the entire question, thus eliminating the need to reopen. :) Does it resemble how mob operates rather than a professional user community? Btw, this is not my allegory, but of some high rep SO users in their blogs (I don't want to finger-point), who refuse to post on Meta anymore.

Comment: @sambul35 Your attitude of ignoring the actual close reason, and just pretending that it doesn't exist, and therefore not trying to fix it, would also explain why you're not getting questions reopened.  If you're unwilling to actually look at the question and try to fix those problems, and just assume that they aren't there, you're not going to fix them, and thus the question won't be reopened.

Comment: @Servy Can you suggest exact edit of my above question that would preserve its substance while allowing others to re-open it, assuming they closed it in good face. I ask you, since I truly have no slightest idea what kind of edit would suffice these folks, except deleting the question. Now, if you refuse to provide such edit wording, but instead will keep teaching me for life as above (looks like trolling), that would mean you don't expect this question be ever re-open regardless of any edits.

Comment: @sambul35 The inappropriate attitude you're showing in these comments is largely why it's closed.  You've pretty clearly demonstrated that you're not actually here to accept input, as the close reason states.  *You* need to be the person to fix that; I can't.

Comment: @Servy May I improve the attitude? And that would presumably allow you to answer my above last question? :) Fine, I'm listening and will consider any input. Are you prepared to give such input: why voters aren't required to provide at least 1st verifiable by asker anonymous justification for their vote, especially to close a question? In particular on SO, how leaving such comment is a bad or harmful thing? Would such comment have a positive educational value at all? Would it make sense as part of the altruistic act to suggest the asker how to imrove the question?

Comment: The problem is folks refuse to answer these questions, but instead claim users aren't prepared to accept their answers. What to accept, if no answer was given whatsoever to the above key policy issue question? If you believe that question was in fact answered, while I "didn't seek that input", pls point in which particular comment it was answered, because I really do seek such input?

Comment: @sambul35 As I've said in my answer, it's not *possible* to close a question without a reason, so your question doesn't apply, as you already *must* provide a reason when voting to close.

Comment: To reiterate what you already understand, the reason chosen to close the question is FAKE. Instead of answering my above question directly on its face, the high privileged users claimed I don't seek input. Similar thing you're doing now - avoiding answering direct question at all cost, but instead manipulating unrelated words back and force - typical spamming technique. And then claim, my attitude is bad, and I don't understand "something". :)

Comment: @sambul35 I cannot directly answer your question because you've asked a nonsensical quesiton.  You're asking why we shouldn't require a reason to be provided when voting to close a question *when a reason is already required when voting to close a question.  It's impossible to answer that question directly because it's based on a false premise.  If you don't like a given person's reason for closing a given question, then you're free to bring that up, but that doesn't change the fact that a reason *was* given.

Comment: Hi Servi. Formally yes. But my question was different: "_verifiable by asker anonymous justification for their vote_". Setting Meta aside (as I don't understand anymore what was the purpose to create this site given every challenging question is immediately closed), and going back to SO where Qs are centered around real coding issues, that usually means a link showing previous answer, or relevant backgrounder, or such. That approach makes the entire rep privilege system justifiable as an unexperienced user always gets some guidance or a way out.

Comment: Now if a "_High signal, low noise_" SO portal as someone put it means absolute lack of guidance except useless or false cliche at downvote or closure, this is "_no signal, maxed out noise_" in my book, so the effect is right opposite, as no positive way out for the asker is achieved whatsoever, especially in coding Qs.

Comment: Like I said, if you think a given question is closed for an improper reason, you're free to bring it up and discuss it, but *a reason is always given*.  Of course, you've now answered your own question of the problem with requiring a reason when voting to close a question, you may just get reasons that you don't like or that don't satisfy you; just requiring that a reason be given doesn't mean you're always going to like it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no context in which voting will *increase* your reputation. In fact, voting like that wouldn't even cause you to *lose* rep.

As it says in the Help Center, these are the *only* ways to lose rep:

- your question is voted down:  −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer:  −1
- you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:
  −100

I think the link in the help center sums it up:
[What's reputation? How do I gain (and lose it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: You do not lose any rep downvoting/close voting/delete voting questions.

Comment: I have updated the answer.