# Edit quality criteria on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, edits

The edit feature is one of the central features of this site. There might be different reasons why a user decides to edit a post. Regardless of the motives:

- Are there any criteria that question edits are expected to comply with on Stack Exchange sites?
- What edits would be viewed as unnecessary to improve the question quality?
- Does it depend on whether the question was already answered, or answer accepted?

Comment: Every edit should improve the quality of the post until it reach reference-like standards.

Comment: ... and some posts aren't worth editing in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam Would you care to link the reference standard you mentioned?

Comment: A relevant issue is, how question edits correlate with downvotes? Should the editor downvote the question he just edited? In what cases it would be expected, and in what sounds unusual? How such downvote would correlate with real motifs for the edit?

Comment: *"Should the editor downvote the question he just edited?"* - I don't think the two are even really related. You should edit if you think you can improve the question, and downvote (before or after) if you think it's still deficient. For example, fixing a post's grammar and formatting is a worthwhile effort, but doesn't make the post show sufficient research effort.

Comment: A while ago, I [proposed a FAQ about editing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit). It's not official, not yet anyway, but I think you''ll find it useful.

Comment: @S.L. Barth I think your FAQ proposal contributes to "reference standard" for questions as well. You might want to consider linking it to "improving questions" related content in FAQ too.

Comment: @PetahChristian May I ask you to explain without generic spamming, what exactly is unclear for you in my above question, and what would it take to make it clear so you will vote to reopen it? Pls suggest the edit wording in your comment that in your view would improve the question clarity. Does it violate Meta posting rules or is negligible compare to vast majority of other questions to the degree closure is mandatory? Does it challenge your privilege to uncontrollably edit others questions?

Comment: @PetahChristian May I suggest you to look at my 2 [other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328396/why-is-demonstrating-subject-competence-not-required-from-stack-overflow-voters) [threads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328287/why-can-questions-be-set-for-review-and-then-deleted-without-voters-justificatio) put on hold that offer what I believe are useful policy improvement _suggestions_, and were closed for the sole reason to hide them from other members under false pretense of being unclear or such, while no improved "clear" version was ever offered by those who closed them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The criteria for edits are mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you
>   observe.

These rules are valid no matter what the post's current score, age or accepted status is. And there are no rules / expected behaviour *after* you edit a post; in the past, I have up-, down- and close-voted posts which I edited.

As @S.L.Barth mentions, posts that can't be saved (because they're spam, or very low quality anyway), no matter how good the edit, should not be edited but flagged and deleted.

Comment: I'd like to see a warning against "turd polishing" in this answer. Apart from that, +1.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you're right. Perhaps it is even better to close this question as a duplicate of your CW.

Comment: Thank you both for contributing to this topic. It addresses some aspects not touched the referenced thread. Such as malicious edits, and correlation between edits and downvotes. In my experience, good face edits are very seldom downvoted by the editors, since the purpose of the edit is to make question better, thus increasing its chance of been answered, instead of suppressing the asker and closing the question. In that regard, would you guys share honestly how many times you edited someone's question on SE sites, and immediately downvoted it? :)

Comment: @sambul35 sadly, there's no way to get this out of the system, but I guess only a handful of times.

Comment: Now, you can ask: "_Why should we talk about negative stuff here at all? Lets pretend, it doesn't exist._" I strongly believe we MUST, and the main purpose is to get rid of such abuse in principle instead of pretending there's none, and ignoring multiple web reports about it and opinions of "mob mentality" on Meta. Your rep scores show, you contribute significant time to help other users. I trust you are as much interested to keep the house clean of privilege abuse. I should mention though, it rather an exception.