# My question is not showing up because of a downvote?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311730/date-parsing-operation-crashes-server) and someone downvoted it for not providing an error, even though I had stated in the post that I had not received any specific error. I even still uploaded a stack trace that did nothing but repeat exactly what I had already said in the question.

After waiting hours for a new reply and not getting any, I decided to search in incognito mode. Turns out my post does not show up and I guess that is because of that one downvote?!

Honestly the downvote feature is helpful but it can get really frustrating when someone mindlessly uses it. I have searched on meta for a solution/similar problem but most are from people who clearly didn't compose their question correctly. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you call my down vote stupid?

Comment: Would you call my upvote stupid?

Comment: Two things: 1) First and very important is that Stack Overflow and the questions posted on it are not bound to any deadlines. So your deadline does not matter if you post a question on Stack Overflow and makes it even worse when you start to spam other users telling them you need the solution. 2) Your question shows up correctly for me no matter if I'm logged in or not.

Comment: @rene Because you just downvoted and left. Didn't even state a reason why it was a bad question. Nothing helpful at all. Stupid is an exaggeration, but it really wasn't helpful at all, and still isn't.

Comment: @Rizier123 I did not spam anyone I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: @RictAcius I don't say that. I just want to say that if a user with a deadline starts spamming that this would make the situation worse.

Comment: @Rizier123 okay no problem. My point is just that people should read a post correctly before downvoting, especially if they don't plan on providing any extra useful information.

Comment: You seem to miss my point. You assume I'm at fault while your question fits for me in *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. That doesn't need an extra comment. And seeing the comments and the (already deleted) answer, unclear it is.

Comment: @RictAcius If you hover over the downvote button you will already see the reason(s) for it. So you really want to go over your question, or give it another person to read, and go through it step by step again making sure your question is clear and contains a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe even take a pause before you go over your question and go to another PC or into a VM and see if you understand the question and if you can reproduce the error just with the information provided in the question in another environment.

Comment: You are just one of the 11,000 SO users that want an answer every day.  On a popular tag like [java] and a busy workday, that gives you about 10 minutes of exposure on everybody's front page.  If you don't fancy anybody's interest then the views quickly stop coming.  And sure, it will *look* like your question is invisible after an hour.  It is not but not that many users make an effort to dig through the tag-specific view.  Only things you can do about it is to not post a half-baked question as a first attempt, hopefully obvious, and to put a bounty on the question to attract more views.

Answer (score 11):

Your question shows up *just fine*.

The reason for the early downvotes was likely due to you not including any relevant detail you could have added to your question.  Not all of us touch anything related to Minecraft server/mod development, but many of us *do* know Java.

It's important for you to include all of the information that you have available to solve your problem, and omit anything that isn't relevant to the problem at hand.  That means omitting things like deadlines, since your timezone isn't (necessarily) our timezone, and your deadlines are definitely not our deadlines.

The more complete your question (and the information you provide for it) is, the less likely you'll get downvoted, and the more likely you'll get helped quicker.

Comment: I understand that, I just got frustrated at how the system allows you to downvote without leaving a comment to say why you're downvoting, so that the author can make the right changes, because one person might think "I have put enough information" and the other might say "They have not put enough information" You can never know unless the downvoter actually tells you what they could not find in your post

Comment: _I just got frustrated at how the system allows you to downvote without leaving a comment to say why you're downvoting:_ This is by intention, please see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/2675154).

Comment: @RictAcius:  Your [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40311730/1) definitely did not include enough information.  If you're getting some kind of error, even if it's not *specific*, including it in your question is ***far*** better than omitting it, since again, not all of us work with Minecraft.   As to why no one generally leaves a comment while downvoting...there could be [any number of reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248), but the actual signal you received was that you needed to improve your question, which you have done to an extent.

Comment: I've figured out what was wrong thanks to a guy I have credited @Jon Skeet. You can find the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40326844/6475970). Sorry for any trouble, but please be more conscious when down voting that the author may not know what's wrong in their post.