# Are code comparison questions too broad?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I recently asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314625/difference-between-builder-mediator-bridge-design-pattern.

Being a member of the community for some time, I understand that open-ended questions always end up closed. What stumped me is that I added some code snippets and asked for explanation about differences in the code snippets, but it was also put `on-hold`.

Does this deserve to be put on hold? I thought I stated the expectation pretty well.

Comment: [foo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto : hmmm....thats answers my comment, what about the question??? :)

Comment: one of those Mondays when `meta` question invites downvotes to SO question!! :\

Comment: It is textbook case of "too broad".  We can have 23 canonical answers on a GoF pattern.  Or we can do it your way and have to maintain 1771 of them.  You already know which approach works best, or should as somebody aiming for the magical 10K rep milestone.

Comment: @HansPassant : wow....no need to be so sarcastic....m not running for reps here, answering questions would fetch me enough of them, dont know why people have become so negative off late!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking down "too broad" and trying to understand it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Comment: "don't know why people have become so negative of late" is a duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's existing precedent which asks for the difference between two design patterns on the site already, *but*...

The question you're directly asking - the one that involves code - is peculiar to me since it really doesn't look like it reflects *any* of those patterns.  The one that sets me off the most is your description of Builder; it doesn't look like the traditional builder pattern that I have implemented or am accustomed to.

What you're asking us to do is to explain these design patterns *as they relate* to the code, and the problem is that I don't believe they relate at all.  You've got code, and design patterns, but the correlation between the two isn't there.

If you're just asking about what these patterns are and how they work, that's something different.  At that point, it might become a duplicate more than anything else, which would be an ideal scenario.  If you *also* want an example with code attached to it - code that fits *this* scenario - I could see the argument being made that your question is too broad.

Comment: firstly, after soo many downvotes, good to see someone answered,thank you for that! :)  Coming to the question, as a learner, I refer different sources online, I used the mentioned git repo as my base for learning as it had gud number of compilation & codes matched the web references, now, if *code-wise*, 2 design pattern look more or less same & I couldn't figure out much online, i post on SO..

"...the correlation between the two isn't there....", this is something i was looking for as an answers and may be, programs were wrong, I was not seeking the DP details, only program comparison!!

Comment: That's kinda my point.  I'm not sure what kind of comparison you were looking for; if it correlated to the design patterns, or with the programs *themselves*.  If it were the latter, it's *definitely* too broad.